# How to skip optional parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

Example:

```
public int foo(int x, int optionalY = 1, int optionalZ = 2) { ... }
```

I'd like to call it like this:

```
int returnVal = foo(5,,8);
```

In other words, I want to provide `x` and `z`, but I want to use the default for `Y`, `optionalY = 1.`

Visual Studio does not like the `,,`

Please help.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If this is C# 4.0, you can use named *arguments* feature:

```
foo(x: 5, optionalZ: 8);
```

See [this blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/01/22/c-4.0-named-parameters-for-better-code-quality.aspx) for more information.

Comment: For the record, I think it's more accurate to call them named *arguments*. Parameters have *always* had names!

Comment: @Jon I agree that it would make more sense, but why then does everyone (including both the links @Josiah and I provide) used the term named parameters? Using Google as a comparison, "named parameters" returns double the results "named arguments" does (using quotes).

Comment: @marcog - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306085/shouldnt-c-4-0s-new-named-parameters-feature-be-called-named-arguments

Comment: @marcog: Not everyone does :) Many people do because some influential writers no doubt did early on. That doesn't mean it's correct to follow their lead. In particular though, the *spec* uses the term "named argument" - see section 7.5.1.

Comment: Do not confuse the C# 4 language and the C# 4 compiler. You can target .net 3.5 and still use optional parameter, as long as you compile with the c#4 compiler

Comment: @Josiah BTW, `optionalX` should be `optionalY` to correctly answer the question.

Comment: @marcog - actually it would be optionalZ if i was reading intentions.

Answer (score 21):

In C# 4.0 you can name the arguments occurring after skipped defaults like this:

```
int returnVal = foo(5, optionalZ: 8);
```

This is called as [named arguments](http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2008/10/28/named-and-optional-arguments-in-c-4-0.aspx). Several others languages provide this feature, and it's common form them to use the syntax `foo(5, optionalZ=8)` instead, which is useful to know when reading code in other languages.

Comment: @Ardman: If the OP is using optional parameters to start with, he must be using C# 4 :)

Answer (score 0):

Another dynamic way to supply parameters of your choise is to implement your method(s) in a class and supply named parameters to the class constructor. Why not even add calls to methods on same line of code as mentioned here : [How to define named Parameters C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056639/how-to-define-named-parameters-c-sharp)

> var p = new PersonInfo { Name = "Peter", Age = 15 }.BuildPerson();