# C# - How to skip parameters with default values?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

Consider the following method example:

```
public void MyMethod (string par1, bool par2 = "true", string par3="")
{
}
```

Now let's say that I call MyMethod and set par3's value to "IamString".

**How could I do that without setting par2's value to true or false?**

I basically want to leave par2 value to its default.

I'm asking this because in Flash's ActionScript it is possible to do that by using the keyword *default* so I could call MyMethod ("somestring", default, "IamString") and par2 would be interpreted as *true*, which is its default value. I wonder if it is possible in C# as well.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630444/how-to-skip-optional-parameters-in-c-sharp

Comment: Named arguments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: Thank you, Sandeep and asawyer, for the references.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
public void MyMethod (string par1, bool par2 = "true", string par3=""){}
Myclass.MyMethod(par1:"par1", par3:"par3");
```

By the way, this won't work: `bool par2 = "true"`

`string par2 = "true"`

or

`bool par2 = true`

Talking about default values, you could also use this to get the default value for a particular type:

`default(T)`

Comment: Thank you! And yeah, you're right bool par2 = "true" won't work. It's a mistake I've did while trying to layout a simple example.

Comment: Yes, it just doesn't let me because you recently edited your answer. I will be able to accept it in 1 minute.

Comment: Warning to anyone who takes this as a correct answer: using default(T) will NOT respect the default value provided in the declaration of the function being called, it will instead use the default value for that type, which for a bool will be false even though the function wants the default value to be true

Answer (score 14):

You can specify this by name the parameter:

```
instance.MyMethod( "Hello", par3:"bla" );
```

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

And there is another bug:

```
bool par2 = true
```

is correct..

Comment: Your answer is equally useful to SeToY's, but I'll accept his because I spotted it first. Nevertheless, thank you and thumbs up!

Comment: This is the correct answer, see my comment on the accepted but incorrect answer