# Difference between arguments/parameters in C#

Tags: c#, parameters, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter)

What is the difference between an argument & a parameter in C#?

Are they the same thing?

Comment: an argument ensues when two programmers cannot agree on the parameters.

Comment: they are used interchangeably but anyway to be accurate check this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_science))

Comment: There are at least two non-closed, language-agnostic versions of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176310/difference-between-parameter-and-argument and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427653/arguments-or-parameters. There's also another C# version of this question; I've requested a merge.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Well, neither keyword is present in the language, so the question is somewhat vague. The best that can be done is to look how each term is used in C# language specification (1.6.6.1 "Parameters"):

> *Parameters* are used to pass values or variable references to methods. The parameters of a method get their actual values from the *arguments* that are specified when the method is invoked.

So, "parameters" refer to *names*, and "arguments" refer to *values* bound to those names. E.g.:

```
void Foo(int x, int y); // x and y are parameters
Foo(1, 2);  // 1 and 2 are arguments
```

Comment: Also called 'Formal Parameters' and 'Actual Parameters' by some.

Comment: +1  "parameters" refer to names, and "arguments" refer to values bound to those names

Answer (score 0):

In the context of functions yes, they are the same, sometimes if you are talking about passing data to executables such as MyApp.exe /a:value /b:somethingelse, this might be refered to as arguments

Answer (score 0):

Typically, I refer to command-line arguments, as arguments. Arguments to a method or function I typically call parameters.

However, this isn't convention and both can be used interchangeably without people getting confused.