# Difference between parameter and argument

Tags: language-agnostic, parameters, arguments, terminology

Is there a difference between a "parameter" and an "argument", or are they simply synonyms?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Argument is often used in the sense of *actual argument* vs. *formal parameter.*

The *formal parameter* is what is given in the function declaration/definition/prototype, while the *actual argument* is what is passed when calling the function — an instance of a formal parameter, if you will.

That being said, they are often used interchangeably, their exact use depending on different programming languages and their communities. For example, I have also heard *actual parameter* etc.

So here, `x` and `y` would be formal parameters:

```
int foo(int x, int y) {
    ...
}
```

Whereas here, in the function call, 5 and `z` are the actual arguments:

```
foo(5, z);
```

Comment: Speaking of terminology, what is the "&c" you used? Does that mean "and vice versa" or something like that?

Comment: "&" is a ligature of "e" and "t", so it means "et", which is latin for "and". The "c" stands for "cetera", which means "(the) other(s)"  (Nom. pl. n.). So you can substitute it with something like "and (the) other things", or "and so on".

Comment: @JakePetroules in other words it is short for "et cetera" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etcetera but I would say (anecdotally) it is more commonly abbreviated etc.

Comment: I'd like to see the &ymology of that usage.

Comment: If I want to avoid all ambiguity, I use "parameter values" instead of "arguments"..

Comment: @donquixote I would say that "parameter values" and "arguments" are not synonyms. For example you may make the following call foo(1, 2, 3) where (in C# for example) the signature of the called method is foo(a, params int[] b). Here the arguments are 1, 2, 3 and the parameter values are 1 and {2, 3}.

Comment: @JoeCool What does "ymology" mean? :-)

Comment: Using the `&c` as an abbreviation for `etc` an answer about _terminology_ is incredibly surprising, and it gets worse as you're using C-esque syntax in your example... i swear I've read "the pointer address of `c`"

Comment: @MestreLion Fixed.

Answer (score 19):

Generally, the parameters are what are used inside the function and the arguments are the values passed when the function is called. (Unless you take the opposite view — Wikipedia mentions alternative conventions when discussing [parameters and arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Parameters_and_arguments)).

```
double sqrt(double x)
{
    ...
    return x;
}

void other(void)
{
     double two = sqrt(2.0);
}
```

Under my thesis, x is the parameter to `sqrt()` and 2.0 is the argument.

The terms are often used at least somewhat interchangeably.

Answer (score 5):

They are often used interchangeably in text, but in most standards the distinction is that an argument is an expression passed to a function, where a parameter is a reference declared in a function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments and parameters are different
in that parameters are used to different values in the program and
The arguments are passed the same value
in the program so they are used in c++.
But no difference in c. It is the same for arguments and parameters in c.