# Use method from another class, java.language.String

Tags: java, ms-access, methods

I've got two classes:

**MAIN** and **DBCONNECT**

**DBCONNECT** has all the coding including the methods that will connect to, insert and update a database/table.

**MAIN** is where my GUI is created and uses the DBCONNECT class.

In my DBCONNECT class I have created a method that writes the input info to a table.

```
String sqlInsert1 = "INSERT INTO Drivers (IDNumber, FirstName, LastName) VALUES " + Id +"," + FirstName+"," + Surname;
String sqlInsert2 = "INSERT INTO Offences(IDNumber, SpeedLimit, DriverSpeed, SeatBelt, DrunkenDriving, DriversLicense) VALUES" + Id + SpeedLimit + DriversSpeed + Seatbelt + DrunkenDriving + License;
String sqlInsert3 = "INSERT INTO DriverPoints(IDNumber, Points) VALUES" + Id + Points;

 public void writeToDB(String sqlInsert1, String sqlInsert2, String sqlInsert3)
    {
        try
        {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(sqlInsert1);
            st.executeUpdate(sqlInsert2);
            st.executeUpdate(sqlInsert3);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Could not read from database");
        }
    }
```

And In my MAIN class I want to use this method when the ***Save*** button is clicked

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if (ae.equals(save))
    {
        database.writeToDB();
    }
}
```

It keeps giving me an error

```
required:java.language.String,java.language.String,java.language.String
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: It is `java.lang.String` If you have the Strings as fields, you don't need to pass them as parameters and you won't have to pass anything.

Comment: @Thanga It means you are trying to call a method which takes one argument, but you haven't given it one.  You need to work out what value you should be passing.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes agreed.. the same scenario was above Jaun's query too, database.writetoDB() invokes the function with  empty params and the definitions has 3 args then how  it is possible with out args please ?  i could be wrong :)

Comment: @Thanga You can do it without args if the method has no parameters. If the values are always the same you don't need to pass them as arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to write like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if (ae.equals(save))
    {
        String sqlInsert1 = "INSERT INTO Drivers (IDNumber, FirstName, LastName) VALUES " + Id +"," + FirstName+"," + Surname;
        String sqlInsert2 = "INSERT INTO Offences(IDNumber, SpeedLimit, DriverSpeed, SeatBelt, DrunkenDriving, DriversLicense) VALUES" + Id + SpeedLimit + DriversSpeed + Seatbelt + DrunkenDriving + License;
        String sqlInsert3 = "INSERT INTO DriverPoints(IDNumber, Points) VALUES" + Id + Points;

        database.writeToDB(sqlInsert1,sqlInsert2,sqlInsert3);
    }
```

It is because your method `writeToDB` accepts three `String` parameters and you are giving no arguments when you are calling it in your code.

And the string variables that you have created before your `writeToDb` method are not the same as the variables declared as parameters in the `writeToDB` method.

Look at this question to know the [difference between arguments and parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176310/difference-between-parameter-and-argument)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding

There is no exact function call writeToDB(); because `writeToDB()` is defined with paramaters but in function call empty parameter have been used .

Instead of this

```
   database.writeToDB();
```

Should use something like this , use those variables and initialize here inside the actionPerformed()

```
   database..writeToDB(sqlInsert1,sqlInsert2,sqlInsert3);
```

Also you have missed the parenthesis in insert statement after values

Example:

```
   sqlINsert1="INSERT INTO Tablename(ID, StreetName, City)Values(,))";
```