# Javascript parameters confusion

Tags: javascript

Below is a code for ordering a pizza. One thing I didn't clearly understand is that getSubTotal has a parameter itemCount and at the end of the line when the function getSubTotal is called the argument inside it is orderCount and not the parameter itemCount. Is it because orderCount is  the argument for the itemCount?

Hope I explained my question clearly.

```
var orderCount = 0;

function takeOrder(topping, crustType) {
  console.log('Order: ' + crustType + ' crust topped with ' + topping);
  orderCount = orderCount + 1;
}

function getSubTotal(itemCount) {
  return itemCount * 7.5;
}

takeOrder('bacon', 'thin');
takeOrder('pepperoni', 'regular');
takeOrder('pesto', 'thin');

console.log(getSubTotal(orderCount));
```

Thank you.

Comment: ItemCount is function local variable

Comment: You should learn about parameters and arguments in coding. Short explanation for javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Comment: Your understanding is correct. `itemCount` is the name of the parameter of the `getSubTotal` function. When you call the function, you are passing `orderCount` as a parameter to the function.

Comment: @alpeware He's passing `orderCount` as the **argument** of the function.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado of course. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly. When you call `getSubTotal(orderCount)`  the function is called with the value of the global variable `orderCount`. At the beginning of the function call, the parameter `itemCount` is set to the value of `orderCount`, then instructions are executed that compute a value which is then returned. Then the *expression* `getSubTotal(orderCount)` equals to the returned value.

`orderCount` is called an *effective argument* (a name or value passed to the function) and `itemCount` a *formal argument* (a name to denote the value passed inside the function).

Answer (score 0):

```
var b=10;
function abc(a){
    return a*10;
}

c=abc(b);
console.log(c);
```

This is what you need. You are basically passing the value of b in

Answer (score 0):

`orderCount` is the value that gets passed to the function in the function call, while `itemCount` is what it gets bound to in the function body. In other words, it's the difference between [formal parameter and actual argument](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3176321/271324).