# PHP parameter and argument question

Tags: php

Are parameters the same as arguments in PHP?

Comment: There are at least two non-closed, language-agnostic versions of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176310/difference-between-parameter-and-argument and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427653/arguments-or-parameters

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of. The parameter is the definition of what you pass to the function. Think of the argument as the actual value or object that you pass.