# What is the proper name for the variables you pass into a function in PHP

Tags: function, parameters, arguments, terminology, optional-parameters

```
function foo($bar,$barbar,$option="") {}
```

Is there a proper term for $bar etc., and/or name for optional variables?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that example, `$bar` is a *parameter*.  Given your example, in a call of `foo(1, 2, 3);` the value `1` would be an *argument*.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427653/arguments-or-parameters) for the distinction.  (tl;dr version: parameters are the slots/variables that hold the arguments.)

`$option` is an *optional parameter*.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I knew this, or at least learned it long ago and forgot it.