# Getting the terminology straight: operands, parameters and arguments

Tags: vb.net, terminology

Please note that this question is **not** a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788923/parameter-vs-argument) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427653/arguments-or-parameters), since the other questions do not have the **operator** component and do not ask about the details of parameters and arguments that I am asking about.

I am going to teach a first programming course using `vb.net`. Please note that this course will cover only procedural programming (with the focus on algorithmic thinking) and will not mention OOP, so no operator overloading.

I am seeking help in getting the terminology straight:

1. Is the following statement correct: a procedure can **have** *parameters*. If a procedure has parameters, then it **accepts** *arguments*?
2. Does the term `parameter` refer only to procedures or also to operators? That is, can I say that a binary **operator** has two **parameters** even when talking about built-in types (such as `Integer`)?
3. Is it wrong to say that an operator **has** *operands*? (just like it is wrong to say that a procedure **has** *arguments*)
4. Is the usage of two different terms -- `argument` and `operand` -- for procedures and operators, respectively, explained only by historical reasons or there is a fundamental difference between the two concepts?
5. Does a `parameter` of a procedure include the parameter's name? I think that in `C++` (with the question asked about *function*s' parameters) the answer is "No"; what is it in `vb.net`?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Parameter" vs "Argument"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788923/parameter-vs-argument)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between parameter and argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3176310/11683)

Comment: If you are starting with VB.NET, you should better focus on actually using the language and not worrying so much about designations.

Comment: @GSerg I have added an explanation of why it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @varocarbas This is the second time I am teaching this course, so I am pretty comfortable with the language. I just want to make sure that I use correct terminology when teaching it.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, my bad. I quickly skimmed through the "this course" part and misread that you were learning, rather than teaching :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. When procedure is called, it *receives* arguments.
2. If you are looking at operator signature like `+(a As Integer, b As Integer)`, *parameters* term is adequate in the context. If you are analyzing its execution then in `2 + 3` you have *operands* and when looking into operator method body, you just received *arguments*.  So look into context.
3. Answered above.
4. Should be clear now. Operands are part of high-level view on operator. If analyzing expression tree, you can speak about operators and their *operands*. But if technically analyzing procedure for given operator, you go with *parameters* and *arguments*.
5. It does not. However, you can get to names using `NameOf()` operator or through the Reflection.