# What different terms mean the same thing (or don't, but people think they do)?

Tags: language-agnostic

One of the pitfalls I run into on a daily basis is customers saying one thing while meaning another.  Usually, this is just due to a miscommunication somewhere, but occasionally they are, in fact, saying the same thing I am just using a different term.

For example, one of my customers the other day mentioned a feature he called, "find as you type."  Being a little confused, I asked him what he meant, and he described the feature in Google where, once you start typing a search query, Google suggests other, popular queries that match the letters you have typed.

Click!  He meant AutoComplete!  He was not wrong, it is just that I had never heard that term before.

In the spirit of reducing confusion, what terms can you think of that are different but mean, essentially, the same thing?

Also, what terms do people think mean the same thing, but don't.  Please differentiate between the two.

Please only one set of terms per answer, so we can vote on the best ones.

Comment: Intellisense is another one for AutoComplete ;)

Comment: The feature you're referring to with Google is actually their Google Suggest feature that's been refined for several years now.  It's not like the typical autocomplete functionality, because rather than querying a list of recently used terms you have entered before on your own computer, it queries against the Google database for popular terms that may be related to what you're typing.  All made possible by the collective technologies we know as AJAX.

Comment: Right.  He meant the auto-completion feature, not the querying mode, which is why I jumped to AutoComplete rather than Google Suggest.

Comment: Ah, the way you wrote it made me think you were referring to Google Suggest.  Never mind then.

Comment: Are we looking for terms that, to the lay person, are synonyms? I suspect you're actually asking for terms that really are synonyms

Comment: @Barry Brown you are correct. I want terms that actually are synonymous. If you want to submit commonly-confused terms, that's fine, just mark it as such.

Comment: Changed title (because I hated the original) to something nearer to the sprit of the question (but still not right, I fear).

Comment: @Neil Butterworth - Changed the title to reflect what I meant.  Hope it is clear now.

Comment: @Mathew Then please don't just rollback - make the title better.

Comment: Browser == Search Engine ;) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4MwTvtyrUQ

Comment: Hey Downvoters! Mind telling me why you do not like this question?

Comment: What I don't like this that you want both synonyms and often confused non-synonyms in the same question. Are the answers one or the other? You say to mark the commonly-confused accordingly, but did the poster forget or do i just not agree?

Comment: It was not clear in the original question what it was asking, so some of the earlier answers did not mark their answers if they were not synonymous.

Answer (score 41):

parameter == argument

> **Parameter** is the variable in the
>   declaration of function or method.
>
> **Argument** is the actual value of this
>   variable that gets passed to function.

I like this one because it happens even to programmers

Comment: @Naveen: Will you accept Klingon jokes to answer that question?

Comment: A parameter is a "hole" that the *developer* leaves in the function *definition*, an argument is what the *user* of that function plugs into that "hole", when *calling* the function.

Comment: @mmyers: I know Javascript as well as Klingon!

Comment: This should be an SO question itself.

Comment: @Barry It is already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter

Comment: These are also referred to, respectively as "formal parameter" and "actual parameter"; see also http://chortle.ccsu.edu/CS151/Notes/chap34/ch34_3.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_science).

Comment: I was thinking to add another misconception: Klingon == cool? I don't think so, hehehe

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag : By which I assume you mean the developer forgets to protect his 'hole'/SQL code against apostrophes, and the user 'plugs' all sorts of ungrammatic it's/its/Sta'ck Overfollow nonsense into the 'hole'.  Clearly the user is more wrong here.

Answer (score 40):

I've seen this a few times on this site:

**Authentication != Authorization**

**Authentication**: Your identity
**Authorization**: Your privileges

Comment: +1 for another common misconception.

Comment: Authentication is "are you who you say you are?".  Authorization is "given who you are, what are you allowed to do?".

Comment: This is seriously a misconception to some people?

Comment: @Janie: if it weren't, then people would have an easy time understanding OpenID. I've stopped using OpenID because no one except programmers seems to get it (and many programmers don't even seem to get it).

Comment: +1 good to see it pointed out, (again!)

Comment: The HTTP spec screwed this up originally.  HTTP 401 says, "unauthorized" but should really be "unauthenticated".  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6937030/155892

Answer (score 16):

Users often confuse "web browser" with "the Internet." I'll hear them say "I'm going to the Internet," which means "I'm launching a web browser."

Comment: "my internet is broken"

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4MwTvtyrUQ

Comment: LOL 3.5 out of 50 got it right :D

Comment: That video goes to show me that users just want to get work done and don't care what the various components are called. It's pointless to try to distinguish between IE and Firefox, Google and Yahoo, and search engines and browsers; to them it's just "the Internet."

Comment: @Barry Brown and that (at least for many people) combining separate things that users see as "related" is helpful. (Like having a search bar built into the browser.) I bet that's part of why Google Chrome has one box that's both a URL bar and a search bar.

Comment: Actually it is not specific to the Internet. You get that confusion every time you develop an app which is an interface to another system.

Comment: My mother often calls me and tells me she "deleted the Internet" and doesn't know what to do.  I finally got her to save the Internet onto a floppy in case this happens again.

Comment: That video's actually pretty misleading since answering "A browser is the software that allows you to navigate to and display web pages" is technically not correct. That's describing a *web* browser, which is a specialized type of browser. File browsers like Nautilus or **Windows** Explorer (not to be confused with Internet Explorer) are still browsers. I'm sure you could even apply the term "Browser" outside of computing - it's so vague.

Answer (score 15):

"CPU" = tower

A favorite term I have heard customers use.

Comment: butbutbut that's the "hard drive"

Comment: That's the CPU?! That's gotta be one big motherboard!

Comment: Where I work, there is an employe that refer to the tower as the "hard disk". It confused me once or twice before I get it.

Comment: Although I understand the difference, I'm guilty of using this colloquialism  :(

Answer (score 13):

AJAX and Javascript.
A lot of times I hear semi-technical people interchanging the two terms. Like: "Can't you animate that image using AJAX". Which is of course just plain javascript.

Comment: ♫ Use AJAX... the foaming cleanser! ♪

Comment: I was once told by a Sr Software Engineer that she was using ajax to sort a table.  Before you think she was right, she was only using JS lol.  This is the same one that asked me what a .sql file was and how to open it.

Comment: JavaScript is just AJAX, without the AX.

Comment: Definitely +1 for the quavers.

Answer (score 12):

"Client" is the big, perennial classic term that means so many things, all within the context of almost every development project.

Comment: "Client" isn't being used as a synonym, though. It just has many different definitions.

Comment: client gets even more fun when using X

Comment: oh the amount of times I've gotten into the XClient debate :P

Comment: One thing is always for sure though.....clients are always getting S - E - R - V - E - D,    OHHHHHH SNAPPPPP!!!!

Answer (score 12):

Hard drive space != RAM

Comment: I agree; the trouble is, the distinction is never worth making because the user who is mentioning either thing is actually talking about something entirely unrelated anyway, oftentimes the orientation of the USB connector.

Comment: Blame this on whoever decided to call them both memory! This rears its ugly head even more when people talk about their digital camera (or whatever) having x amount of memory. The term memory is or course accurate but people think that the word "memory" only refers to one thing. This short term vs long term stuff is understandably confusing to layfolk.

Answer (score 10):

Verification == Validation

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verification_and_validation):

> It is sometimes said that validation
>   can be expressed by the query "Are you
>   building the right thing?" and
>   verification by "Are you building the
>   thing right?". "Building the right
>   thing" refers back to the user's
>   needs, while "building it right"
>   checks that the specifications be
>   correctly implemented by the system.
>   In some contexts, it is required to
>   have written requirements for both as
>   well as formal procedures or protocols
>   for determining compliance.

Comment: @skaffman good one!  Hear this all the time. +1.

Answer (score 9):

"open source" == "free software"

If you watch [Revolution OS](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=7707585592627775409), you'll hear Richard Stallman use the term "free software" and others like Linus Torvalds and Bruce Perens use "open source." After watching the film, I think they're talking about the same thing, but disagreeing (vehemently in some cases) on what to call it.

(I hope none of them are reading this.)

Comment: The software itself is free, what is not is the documentation, support, manuals, etc, etc...

Comment: And neither term should be confused for "license-free".

Comment: They are talking about the same thing in the practical sense, but very different things in the philosophical sense.  Free Software is a social movement.  Open Source software is somewhere between a development technique and a way to talk about Free Software without sounding like Stallman, inclusive.  The difference in the Free Software Foundation's definition of Free Software and the Open Source Initiative's definition of Open Source Software is almost trivial, though.

Answer (score 9):

"Inconceivable"

I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: I think it means what I think it does.

Comment: My name is Diego Montoya, you killed my Father - prepare to die!

Comment: @belugabob: it's "Inigo Montoya" (see http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0003786/) - awesome quote though.

Comment: I knew it was wrong, as I was typing it, but went with the flow of the moment. :-)

Comment: Inconceivable \In'con*ceiv"a*ble\, adjective [Pref. in- not + conceivable: cf. F. inconcevable.] Not conceivable; incapable of being conceived by the mind; not explicable by the human intellect, or by any known principles or agencies; incomprehensible; as, it is inconceivable to us how the will acts in producing muscular motion.

Answer (score 8):

I once heard a junior dev use NULL and VOID interchangeably.

Scariest thing I'd ever heard.

Comment: wow i've actually never heard someone confuse the 2

Comment: Void is the absence of a variable, Null is a variable with undefined/zero value.

Comment: Danger, Brad Gilbert! [re: zero]

Answer (score 7):

Drop down = Combo box

Comment: Or Picklist in the MSCRM world.

Comment: so how its different? one is on the web and on on the desktop?

Comment: Drop down list = what you you get when you use the select tag in HTML. Combo box = a combination of a drop-down list or list box and a single-line textbox where the user can either type a value directly into the control or choose from the list of existing options (e.g. the font selector in the Formatting toolbar in Word or Excel.)

Answer (score 7):

Wiki != Wikipedia. (As in, "Well I looked it up on Wiki, and it says...")

This one is not really programming related, but it could cause a problem for someone working at a company that had their own internal wiki.

Wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:About

Some wikis that are not Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wikis

Comment: Yes, I hear that one all the time and it bugs me.

Comment: I find it hilarious that your list of wikis that aren't Wikipedia is a Wikipedia page.  =)

Comment: I understand the difference but I admit that I'm guilty of this one as well. My spouse and I often say we'll "look it up in Wiki."

Comment: @chazomaticus, I hope that didn't confuse people. It's just that if I need a list of something, I usually go to Wikipedia to find it. =)

Answer (score 7):

Java == Javascript

Answer (score 5):

Winchester == hard disk drive.

It ain't!

[alt text http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Winchester_Model_1873_Short_Rifle_1495.jpg/300px-Winchester_Model_1873_Short_Rifle_1495.jpg](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Winchester_Model_1873_Short_Rifle_1495.jpg/300px-Winchester_Model_1873_Short_Rifle_1495.jpg)

Comment: Winchester refers to the first hard drive with a sealed head/disk assembly released by IBM in 1973. It was named after the Winchester 30-30 rifle due to its original capacity of two 30MB platters. All modern disk drives use this technology or a derivative of it. That's why some people refer to them as 'Winchesters'.

Comment: The only times I hear people call them winchesters is as a joke. I do it myself when I encounter a particularly pedantic individual, just to wind them up. I also call them "spindles", which works even better.

Comment: Winchester is the most common way to refer to a hard drive in Russian. Also called Vint (a screw/bolt, but also a short version of Vinchester, a Russian pronunciation of Winchester).

Answer (score 4):

Scope != Lifetime

Scope :: is the collection of statements where a variable can be referenced. Those statements are called the referencing environment of that variable.

Lifetime :: is the association between a variable(the name) and its place of storage in memory(address).

Answer (score 4):

Closure == lambda. In reality, they are distinct things: lambda is any anonymous function, and may or may not close over some variables; closure is any function that closes over some variables, and may or may not be anonymous. For example, the original Pascal had no lambdas, but it had closures (in form of nested functions).

Answer (score 4):

deprecate != depreciate

Seriously people.  Features are not depreciated from upcoming releases of software.  They are deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

hard disk drive = computer

Comment: I get that all the time. People call that black thing under their desk the "hard disk" instead of the computer.

Answer (score 3):

System == Library == Framework == Program == Application == Software

Answer (score 3):

There are 180 pages of preferred terms in the "[Microsoft Manual of Style for Technical Publications](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=6074&locale=en-us)," which is a great book for technical writers, but I think programmers should have it too.

Many of the entries mention unacceptable (or outdated) equivalents.

Example: "**system tray**  Do not use. Use *notification area* instead."

Comment: Yeah, right.  I know where and what my system tray is.  Without reading that, I wouldn't have a clue where or what the notification area is.

Comment: Haha. That's what I thought, too. That's why that one jumped out at me. :-)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/10/54831.aspx

Comment: http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1="system+tray"&word2="notification+area"

Comment: I think I will end my life a happy man if I never catch a glimpse of that book.

Answer (score 3):

PowerPoint != the projector

It really bothers me when people say "I'll just put it up on the PowerPoint" and then they go to Microsoft Word or something instead.

Answer (score 3):

Bug - Incident - Failure - Error - Defect - Problem - Issue

Comment: Good one. Some of these terms are also confusingly used to describe the "ticket"/"incident" where the bug, issue etc is recorded. E.g. Jira overloads the term ["issue"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/What+is+an+Issue). Bugs/defects and issues can mean different things, e.g. a bug is something that is not working properly with the software whereas an issue is something that has been raised as a concern, e.g. it may cause problems now or later down the line (e.g. a problem with the design or architecture).

Answer (score 3):

Some users will use the term "downloading" to generally mean "transferring" instead of distinguishing between "downloading" and "uploading."  So, if they say "The error happened right after I downloaded the data," it might refer to another part of the process than what a tech person would take it to mean.

Answer (score 3):

One that really turned my head around was someone in my QA department referring to a ***null*** value and a ***blank*** value as being one and the same.  I smiled and asked if they were serious and they said, "of course they're the same."  I tried to explain as simply as I could that they were not the same and it just didn't register with them.

/matt

Comment: I recommend this question. Perhaps a simple way to explain it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694204/explaining-null-and-empty-to-your-6-year-old

Answer (score 3):

PC != Windows

PC means personal computer. Apple invented the PC. But, now it's taken a life of its own as anything that has Windows on it.

In this same vein, people tend to compare "Mac" or "PC" when it should be "OS X" or "Windows"... or "Mac vs. ThinkPad/Satellite"

Of course, that would be more difficult to put into an ad.

Comment: While there have been many "Personal Computers" over the years, IBM started the term with their "PC" models, that ran Microsoft DOS.  Many other companies made "PC-Compatible" machines, and eventually the term became the generic for an MS-DOS box.  While Windows has replaced DOS in the same space, the term carried over.  "Wintel" is perhaps a more descriptive term for the platform, but this is a case where the common usage rather than accuracy makes the definition.

Comment: True, but it's really only got steam as "anything that's not a Mac" in recent years, in part due to the Apple ads. I always remembered them being called: "IBM compatible" not "PC Compatible". Compaq was the first one to create a clone.

Answer (score 2):

computer == system == workstation == machine == box

Comment: So this is a computer? http://www.geocities.com/pubot5/cardboardbox.jpg

Comment: "...terms that mean the same thing *or don't*..."

Comment: @Ólafur: One of the guys I work with has asked me on more than one occasion, "What box are you using?" and every time it takes me a moment to overcome my initial confusion. Because the image you linked to is exactly what appears in my head.

Comment: @Eli is your joke bone broken?

Comment: @Eli: "Please differentiate between the two."

Comment: geocities is no more! :(

Answer (score 2):

Hyperlink = Link = Anchor

I've run across people who use these terms interchangeably, and of course, they aren't the same thing.

Comment: But the 'link' tag in HTML is distinct from the 'a' tag. :-(

Comment: You're right of course.  I think when the question had originally been asked, it wasn't clear that these were meant to be terms that are synonymous, rather than terms that are commonly used as being synonymous, if that makes any sense.  I'll edit my response.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever dealing with Departments of Education you must learn that "system" means software and "technology" means hardware.

Comment: It's a "system"! "A group of interacting, interrelated, or interdependent elements forming a complex whole."[1] that include both software *and* hardware in the case of a computer. 1:http://www.answers.com/topic/system

Answer (score 2):

Host == Server

.. Which is untrue :)

Comment: Why is this not true? If something is hosting something, it's 'serving' it, therefore it's a server.

Comment: Yeah, your logic makes sense, which is why so many people (including myself) have had it wrong for so long time. In network terminology, a host can be a client, a server, a bridge-adapter etc... A host is simply a node in the topology, while a server is the node that accepts incoming connections.

Comment: aren't these two different types of "host"? the topology one and the server one (should it be existing).

Answer (score 2):

Value Object == Value Type

Value Objects are *classes* representing immutable attributes, as in Domain Driven Design.

Value Types are *variables* whose values are held on the stack (int, bool, struct, etc). These are spoken of in relation to Reference Types, which live on the heap and have memory pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Also *Architecture* is a term that requires constant clarification. It means topology to some. To others it means class diagrams, the product of software engineering. To others it is just a catch all for the above and umpteen other concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Operating System == Kernel who manages hardware and gives a very basic API vs. the whole software distribution

Answer (score 2):

Programmer == Developer == Software engineer

[You need developers, not programmers](http://www.ericsink.com/No_Programmers.html) by Eric Sink

Comment: == software engineer.  I've never actually paid much attention to my title, but I've had a fairly large number of jobs doing essentially the same thing, and the titles have varied widely.

Comment: I'd disagree and say programmer does not necessarily == developer.   At least in the context of web development.

Comment: @Cuga yes that's precisely my post's reason ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've had this one come up when trying to explain Cocoa development

Apple != Mac != Mac OS

Apple is a company

Mac is a brand

Mac OS is an operating system

The same is often true for

Microsoft != Windows

Comment: And MAC means Media Access Control.

Comment: ...And mac addreess is not 1 Infinite Loop Cupertino, CA 95014

Comment: I thought mac was a waterproof raincoat? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mackintosh

Answer (score 2):

Compiler == Programming Language == IDE

Answer (score 2):

Memory == Hard Drive as in "My PC has 30GB of memory!"

Comment: Well, "My PC has (roughly) 30GB of memory" is no longer unrealistic on x64...

Comment: hdd == ram got far more points.. interesting

Answer (score 2):

Declaration != Definition

I heard so many times people confusing the two that now I confuse them myself.

Answer (score 2):

Hang == crash == some error message the user didn't even read.

Answer (score 2):

IDE != framework

Q: "What frameworks do you consider yourself to be proficient in?"

A: "Visual Studio"

Not mine, but a friend told me this yesterday. About died, both from laughing too hard and crying over the sad state of humanity.

Answer (score 2):

In many video-games, I see computer controlled players labeled "CPU".

CPU != Bot

Comment: I think it means that the choices that decide the (usually virtual) acts of those bots are made "*in the CPU*", instead of "*in player n's brain*".

Answer (score 1):

Client == End User

They *can* be the same person, but more often then not the one writing the check to you is not the one that uses the thing you built.

Comment: but but... isn't the client software and the end user a person?

Answer (score 1):

History and Travellog (as applied to webbrowsers).

- History is the list of all websites you have visted ever (or for the last N days).
- Travellog is the list of sites in your current session that are accessible via Back and Forward.  And yes, I realize the JavaScript object for this is called history.

Comment: I guess Javascript uses history because travellog term is so unknown and it may refer to 'current session history' which is the same

Comment: WPF calls the latter thing a "journal".

Comment: I think what you call a travellog is called "session history" in some places in Firefox. Which actually makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

process = procedure = plans

Answer (score 1):

Google == Internet

also

Google == Search

Talked to many people that think Google **IS** the internet.  If Google shutdown, that would be the end of being 'online'.

Where did you find xyz?  Oh, on Google.  Where is xyz stored?  In Google.

Note: This also says a lot for Google's ability to sell their brand.  When your company's name is well known as a verb 'to Google' you know you are successful.

Comment: Actually, theoretically if the "Google" (as in all search engines) were to shutdown temporarily, you could argue that it would become the end of being online.  All you would know was what was in your bookmarks/delicious etc. and the URLs you knew by memory (SO, xkcd, umm...).  So although the word Google is now generic, the concept of search - or as I'm told it is in 2009, discoverability - is more akin to what the 'internet' is about to most people, than the content and the concept of hyperlinking.  The bad old days of site1-site2-site3 link following rarely exist now, due to search.

Comment: I disagree Alistair. There is a whole lot more to the internet than Browsing and searching. Look at all the mobile apps, B2B commerce Online Storage, email etc. Search engines just facilitate browsing web sites.

Answer (score 1):

C# .Net (Ahhhhh!)

Answer (score 1):

Pass values by reference != pass references by value.

Pass values by reference in C++:

```
struct Bar
{
   int X;
   Bar(int x) : X(x) {}
   Bar &operator=(const Bar &rhs) { X = rhs.X; }
};

void foo(Bar &b, Bar &b2)
{
    b = Bar(1);
    b2.X = 1;
}

int main()
{
    Bar b(0);
    Bar b2(0);
    foo(b, b2);
    cout << b.X << ", " << b2.X; // prints 1, 1
}
```

Pass references by value (C# / Java)

```
class Bar
{
   public int X;
   public Bar(int x) { X = x; }
}

void foo(Bar b, Bar b2)
{
    b = new Bar(1);
    b2.X = 1;
}

int main()
{
    Bar b = new Bar(0);
    Bar b2 = new Bar(0);
    foo(b, b2);
    Console.Write("{0}, {1}", b.X. b2.X); // prints 0, 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A bilingual (swedish - english) misunderstanding :

"Fält" which translates to field, but in swedish programming books is array. (It is not the books that are wrong, what i'm saying is that sometimes when newbies try to ask for help online they ask about fields, when they actually mean array.

Answer (score 0):

From non-embedded software engineers:

- RAM == program memory == data memory

For typical lower-end embedded processors (e.g. PIC, STM32, etc), code and constant data are stored in, and normally accessed from, flash; non-constant data is stored in RAM.

- 1 Mb == small

For these kinds of processors, 1 Mb of flash is a lot (though not as much as it used to be). For example, the [STM32](http://www.st.com/mcu/inchtml-pages-stm32.html) that I'm using currently using has 128 Kb of flash, and 8 Kb of RAM.

At the other end of the spectrum, the smallest [PIC10F](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en019863) has 384 bytes of flash, and 16 bytes of RAM.

Comment: No one will need more than 637 kb of memory for a personal computer.

Answer (score 0):

"Find as you type" == "incremental search": The feature in Firefox and some other programs where, as you are entering your search term in a Find dialog/field, the document jumps to the position of the position of the next search result based on what you have entered so far (without you actually having to click a "Search" button to initiate the search action).

This is primarily handy to avoid typing (for example) "incremental search[enter]" when typing "incr" is probably good enough to find what you're looking for!

This came to mind as a meaning of "find as you type" different than the example given in the original question!

Answer (score 0):

Q: "Where did you get this file?"
A: "I got it offline."

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint Presentation == Any Computerbased Presentation (not necessary made with PowerPoint)

Always when I hear People talking about a presentation made and presented with computer and projector, they say "PowerPoint presentation" because they haven't got any term which is more general. Most of them use OpenOffice, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

I get this one way too often:

"Specification" == "Suggestion"

When you're on a hardware team and you have software teams treating your hardware specs as "optional guidelines", it makes you want to slap somebody.

Answer (score -1):

### Search box != Address Bar

Time after time, people type a Url in the search box ( be it Google, Yahoo, Bing, Teoma )

Comment: In Google's Chrome browser (and others, most likely), these are indeed one and the same.

Comment: Hmmm... you mean `Google's` browser has only a search box? Remember, there is also a search box on the Google.com page. People type URLs in that search box as well.