# What is a Trusted Connection?

Tags: sql-server, trustedconnection

What is a trusted connection in terms of SQL Server 2005 (Trusted vs Windows Auth)?

Comment: For google travellers, format of conn string is <add name="MyDbConn1"connectionString="Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>

Comment: @fiat also https://www.connectionstrings.com is very handy

Answer (score 79, accepted):

A trusted connection is the same thing as using Windows Authentication in SQL Server 2005. Authentication is done by the domain, and authorization is handled by SQL Server.

SQL Server can also use its own logins, such as the `sa` user. These are both authenticated and authorized by SQL Server. They are only viable if SQL Server is run in Mixed Authentication Mode.

MSDN has a good article about [choosing the right Authentication Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx). It's a good primer.

Comment: @Mitch: My highest voted answer ever is that difference. How sad is that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045107/what-different-terms-mean-the-same-thing-or-dont-but-people-think-they-do/1049435#1049435

Answer (score 19):

A Trusted connection means Windows Authentication (i.e. a Windows login).

SQL Server has two Authentication modes: Mixed and Windows Authentication Mode.

Mixed has the option of SQL server logins (username and password) and Windows Authentication.

Comment: so trusted connection is based on windows logon id?

Comment: Yes.  Trusted loosely means "windows logins".