# Risks of a Non Trusted Connection to SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security, sqlconnection, trustedconnection

What is the risk of not using a trusted connection?

For example here is a scenario: I have created a very simple application which only has 4-5 lines of codes which uses an SQL connection with my connection string within web.config, and sends a select command to my database, and display results in an interface.

What are the security weakness here?

Edit:

I know trusted connection is related to authentication, what I wonder is I don't know how can the system be hacked if I don't use it ? (I will use my application at my company's servers and the application is a public application, so every company member can use it, so why do I need a trusted connection if it is a local company application ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To look at it the other way around, the main benefit of trusted connections is that you do not have to manage passwords in your application. If your application needs a password to connect to SQL Server, then where do you put the password (or connection string) so that the application user (or other developers, or sysadmins, or external consultants, etc.) cannot read it but you can still change it easily when required?

Passwords in files or the registry can often be read by users because when they run the application it has to retrieve the password, therefore the user needs access. Or a sysadmin or consultant has access to the filesystem where an application config file is. Obfuscating the password with some form of encryption is possible, but then you have to secure and manage the decryption key. Hard-coding the password in the application makes it difficult to change and also makes it highly likely that the password will be visible in the source control system, which is typically a relatively insecure system (in practice, if not by design). You can create a web service that the application gets the password from on startup but then you have to authenticate access to the service somehow.

Using trusted authentication avoids all of this completely by making the operating system responsible for authentication and unless you are a world-class security programmer, the odds are good that Windows provides a more reliable mechanism than you can create yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> I will use my application at my company's servers and the application
>   is a public application, so every company member can use it, so why do
>   I need a trusted connection if it is a local company application ?

Security risks in non trusted connection lies how you store SQL server passwords and use them in application. if you store passwords in config file or hard code in program, any other developer who has access on your code can view it and on the worst can change database in such a way that may break application or steal sensitive information. it will be a privacy breach as well and your company may be sued for this ( you can't just imagine what can happen).

@Pondlife has also elaborated very well.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the only extra layer of security a trusted connection gives is authentication. If you use a trusted connection then Windows will authenticate your connection in Active Directory.

A quick google yields this link:

[What is a Trusted Connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250552/what-is-a-trusted-connection)

Comment: I know trusted connection is related to authentication, what I wonder is I don't know how can the system be hacked if I don't use it ? (I will use my application at my company's servers and the application is a public application, so every company member can use it, so why do I need a trusted connection if it is a local company application ?)

Comment: In case somehow your SQL server gets exposed to the wider internet and somehow somebody managed to get a SQL username and password. 

I agree with you ... I never use it.