# Trusted_Connection and Encrypt in Azure SQL connection string?

Tags: azure, database-connection, connection-string, azure-sql-database

A typical Azure SQL Database connection string is as follows:

```
Server=[server];
Database=[database];
User ID=[user];
Password=[password];
Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;
Connection Timeout=30;
```

**What are the `Trusted_Connection` and `Encrypt` properties for?**

If I exclude them, then I cannot connect to the database from my Azure VM service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Encrypt` is indication that Azure SQL Database requires explicit encryption of the communication. It will refuse any unecrypted connections.

`Trusted_Connection` is set to explicitly confirm using of SQL Server authentication as opposed to integrated Windows Authentication ([check this SO question on "What is Trusted Connection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250552/what-is-a-trusted-connection))

Both parameters are required to be set with respective values in order to successfully connect to SQL Azure.