# If storing the password in a connection string is a security risk, what's the alternative in Visual Studio Report Website?

Tags: security, visual-studio-2012

I'm working through a tutorial to become familiar with using Visual Studio, and selected the Report Website option.  In the datasource connection wizard, I selected ODBC and there's a question asking Yes/No to save sensitive information in the connection string, along with a note stating it's a security risk to do so.  So I selected No.

Now what?  How do I connect?  When I run the basic report, there's an error "Cannot create a connection to data source"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure it is set as a "Trusted Connection".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811006.aspx

> Trusted_Connection
>   This parameter specifies whether the data source should use trusted connections when connecting to SQL Server. 1 specifies trusted connections; omitting the parameter specifies no trusted connections. For more information, see "Integrated and Standard Security."

To set a trusted connection [set the following parameter in your connection string instead of `User Id` and `Password`](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/)

`Trusted_Connection=True;`

For more info on this see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250556/413180).

You can also [encrypt the connection strings stored in web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx). See the section marked "Encrypting Configuration File Sections Using Protected Configuration" in the linked page.

Comment: where do I set it as "Trusted" ?  And is that the only option besides storing the password in the connection?