# SQL Server + windows service + account/connectionstring

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-services, sql-server-2012

I'm creating a Windows service that accesses tables in a SQL Server database.

How would I go about streamlining this, so I don't have to hardcode the username and password in the connection string?

It only needs read and write and query notifications (I don't know if there are explicit rights for that).

What are my options?

And which would be the best solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [Windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250552/1810429) to avoid a username and password in the connection string at all.

Here are a couple examples from an older [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx):

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDbConn1" 
      connectionString="Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>
  <add name="MyDbConn2" 
      connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyDb;Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

What the connecting SQL Server [login](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) and mapped database [user](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) can do - e.g. create and delete tables - is just a matter of the roles you assign and permissions you grant using SQL Server's security mechanisms.

Comment: so i need to start my windows service as a service account which has permission on the sql server?

Comment: @AlekCarlsen: If you are using Windows authentication to connect to SQL Server, yes.