# Why not a 'params' array in Java main method?

Tags: java

As a Java rookie, I understand that the values that I pass to a method are called the arguments and the variables that receive the values in the method definition are called parameters.

Now, where ever I see a Java class written with main method, the method signature says

public static void main(String **args**[])
{}

For eg. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Though I can give any variable names, wasn't it justifying if they had given **params[]** instead of args[]?

Any theories?

Comment: I vote for Args...it sounds better when said with a pirates voice.

Comment: @steve ur right ...sounds good calling 'args' than 'params' :)

Comment: I usually call it "params" when I actually use the parameters, and "ignored" or "egal" (german for "does not matter") when I don't use them.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter

Answer (score 5):

There's no reason you couldn't call it whatever you wanted, honestly. It's just convention to call it `args`. I wouldn't recommend calling it anything but `args`, because that is what virtually every Java programmer expects. But there's nothing that says you couldn't rename it.

```
class BadArgs {
    public static void main(String params[]) {
        System.out.println(params[0]);
    }
}

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>javac BadArgs.java

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java BadArgs Hello!
Hello!
```

Answer (score 4):

The name is appopriate. `args` is a single *parameter* whose value is an array of command line *arguments*.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, this is a fairly canonical name in many languages.  e.g. in C, you normally see `main` defined as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

(where `argc` is the count, and `argv` is an array of pointers to each argument).  Java mimics this.

I can only guess as to why the canonical name is `args` and not `params`.  Perhaps it's because if you want to know e.g. the 0-th arg, you refer to `args[0]`?

Answer (score 4):

The values passed to a function are arguments. The named variables that contain those arguments are called parameters. So it would be quite valid to name the parameters `arg1`, `arg2` in every method if you wanted to be vague!

The answers to this question may make it clearer (or not):

[What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

It could really go either way, args is pretty much the same thing as params, i guess they call it args because its command line "args" that are the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

main() is a special method.  and args[] is referring to the fact that the main function receives command-line arguments when the program starts from the user of the program.