# create two dimensional array that can store integer values inside, and square them in different method and print them in another method

Tags: java

Complete question is: Create a program  that  uses a  two  dimensional  array  that  can  store  integer values  inside.  (Just create  an  array  with  your  own  defined  rows  and columns).  Make  a  method  called  Square,  which  gets  each  of  the  value inside the array and squares it. Make another method called ShowNumbers which shows the squared numbers.
*What I attempted thou it has errors:*

```
public class SquareMatrix {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int sqr[][]= {{1,3,5},{2,4,6}};
  System.out.println("Your Original Matrix: ");
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
  System.out.print(sqr[i][j] + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();
  }
  Square();
  ShowNumbers();
  }
static void Square(){
    
  for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
  sqr[i][j] = sqr[i][j] * sqr[i][j];
  } 
  }
  }
  static void ShowNumbers(){
      
  System.out.println("Matrix after changes: ");
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
  System.out.print(sqr[i][j] + " ");   
  }
  System.out.println();
  }
} 
}
```

Also how would I write it if I wanted an input from the user for the col and row for a specific range of 0 to 10, I made an **alternative version** with many errors below. **Below code is not as important as the one above**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     
     int row, col, i, j;
       int arr[][] = new int[10][10];
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      try{
       System.out.print("Enter Number of Row for Array (max 10) : ");
       row = scan.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter Number of Column for Array (max 10) : ");
       col = scan.nextInt();
       if(0>=row && row<=10 || 0>=col && col<=10 ){
           }
      }
       catch (Exception e){
           System.out.println("(!) Wrong input...\n");
       }
       
       System.out.print("Enter " +(row*col)+ " Array Elements : ");
       for(i=0; i<row; i++){
           for(j=0; j<col; j++){
               arr[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
           }
       }
    }
       static void square(){
        arr[row][col] = arr[row][col] * arr[row][col];
       }
       
       static void ShowNumbers(){
       System.out.print("The Array is :\n");
       for(i=0; i<row; i++)
       {
           for(j=0; j<col; j++)
           {
               System.out.print(arr[i][j]+ "  ");
           }
           System.out.println();
       }}}
```

*PS I am new to java and would appreciate a response with the whole code pasted not just a section of the code so I don't get lost or with the number of the line the error is from.*
*thanks for any help*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular How do [I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."
even if it is no homework.
Please add the **complete error message*

Comment: I down voted because ["It's not working" is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: I don't understand what you talking about. If you really want to know what is not working on the first lines of code, the method Square is not recognizing the variables, and the second one I already mentioned in the question

Comment: @HussainAlAdraj Fix the indentation of your source code. This made it easier for everyone (specially you) to read and understand the code.

Comment: @HussainAlAdraj You can provide the values as parameters to your methods. That way you can call these methods like `Square(sqr);`

Comment: @progman I Got errors: SquareMatrix.java:14: error: <identifier> expected
static void Square(sqr){

Comment: @HussainAlAdraj Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625043/how-to-use-parameters-and-arguments-in-java on how to define parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are starting from scratch, it would be good to go over the basics of the language again. Take a look at [oracle classvars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) For your upper problem you need to understand the difference between local and instance variables and the difference between static and non static variables respectively. To solve your issue just move the declaration of your array out of the main method and add a static modifier:

```
public class SquareMatrix {
    static int sqr[][] = {{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //rest of your code
}
```

Comment: @HussainAlAdraj You are welcome. Glad I could help.