# how can i send an int value made by a scanner from one of my methods to another method

Tags: java

how can I send an *int* value made by a scanner from one of my methods to another method.
Also, how can I also send it to my main and then send it to another method

Comment: [The Java Tutorials - Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) - [The Java Tutorials - Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: Parameters and return values. See other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625043/how-to-use-parameters-and-arguments-in-java

Answer (score 0):

To pass a value, you use parameters:

```
public static void main()
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);// creates keyboard scanner
    int thisInt = scan.nextInt(); // user types 5
    example(thisInt);             // it is passed 5
}
```

If the method "example" was passed the number with **thisInt**

```
public void example(int value)
{
    System.out.print(value);         // prints that 5
}
```

It would print the value, **thisInt**, or 5.

**EDIT FOR MORE INFO**

The **void** on that method is the reason nothing is returned.
With this VERY VERY BASIC code:

```
public int example(Scanner scan)
{
    return scan.nextInt()
}
```

You can return a read number to main like so:

```
int newNumber = example(new Scanner(System.in));
```

Answer (score -2):

you can declare it as static parameter value and then you can get it from anywhere 
example:
`static int value=null;`
to get 
`ClassWhereValueIsDeclared.value`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).