# Hard Time figuring out how to use user input in a for loop in Java

Tags: java

I have tried for a while to make a simple program, but since I'm new at it, it's taking me a bit to pick up on it. I'm following these instructions

1. declare and initialize a `char` variable for the student grade;
2. use a for loop that has five iterations;
3. use the `System.out.println()` method in the for loop to request a grade from the student;
4. use the `System.in.read()` method to receive student grades in the for loop;
5. use the `System.out.println()` method to tell the student to try again if they enter anything other than one letter for a grade;
6. use the `System.out.println()` method after the for loop to output a message for the student; and,
7. compile and run your program.

This is how far I've gotten with no errors when I run it.

```
package grading.on.a.loop.java;
public class GradingOnALoopJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char studentgrade = 100;
        System.out.println("Please enter your Grade here.");
        for(int counter = 75; counter <= 100; counter += 5) {
            System.out.println(counter);
            System.out.println("Please enter your Grade.");
        }
    }
}
```

this is when I start to run into problems:

```
package grading.on.a.loop.java;
public class GradingOnALoopJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char studentgrade = 100;
        System.out.println("Please enter your Grade here.");
        for(int counter = 75; counter <= 100; counter += 5) {
            System.out.println(counter);
            System.out.println("Please enter your Grade.");
            System.in.read("");
        }
    }
}
```

The "`System.in.read`" part is giving me a bit of trouble, no matter what I've done to alter it, it always shows an error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `read` does not take any parameters and you are passing an empty String.

Comment: `read` returns an `int` so you can use `int b = System.in.read();`

Comment: @Kon It is generally difficult to remember the difference between parameters and arguments :D

Comment: @AniketSahrawat In Java they are used interchangeably from every source I've ever seen. EDIT: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709026/difference-between-arguments-and-parameters-in-java

Comment: You need to use a letter, a single char, not multiple chars. That’s what the assignment is looking for

Comment: @Kon In almost every language issue is the same, even I get pretty confused between params and args. Anyways, check this out *[Parameters refers to the list of variables in a method declaration. Arguments are the actual values that are passed in when the method is invoked.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)*. I don't want to enter into any debate because this is silly ;-)

Comment: Then after reading all this, how do you put in a line in such code ^^^^ to accept user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `read()`, you should initialize a scanner and use that.

This is what it would look like:

```
package grading.on.a.loop.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradingOnALoopJava
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String[] grades = new String[5];

        for(int counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println(counter * 5 + 75);
            System.out.print("Please enter your Grade: ");
            grades[counter] = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```