# access to function return value within another function python

Tags: python, oop

I have a program like this with a class StatFind. This class has three methods. ncount method returns a list of dictionaries: 'finallist'.  I need to add each of these dictionaries from the list into a mongodb database.

How do I access the finallist inside of my inserttomongo() method.

The code currently gives a nameerror:

```
s.inserttomongo(finallist)
#=> NameError: name 'finallist' is not defined
```

Here is my code:

```
!/usr/bin/python
import pymongo,json
from datetime import date, timedelta
from collections import defaultdict
import os, sys,time,csv,glob

tsvs = glob.glob(sys.argv[1])

class StatFind:
  def __init__(self,tsvs):
    self.tsvs=tsvs

  def ncount(self, tsvs):
    if True:
      finallist=[]
      for path in tsvs:
         ....Someprocess....
         returns a list
      return finallist

  def other(self):
    samplestring= "something random"
    print samplestring

  def inserttomongo(self, finallist):
     self.finallist=ncount().finallist
     mongo=pymongo.Connection('localhost')
     mongo_db=mongo['sample']
     mongo_collection=mongo_db['users']
     for dictvalue in self.finallist:
      #  for dictvalue in ncount(tsvs):
       insert_id=mongo_collection.insert(dictvalue)

s=StatFind(tsvs)
s.ncount(tsvs)
s.other()
s.inserttomongo(finallist)
```

Comment: Guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter might be helpful to you. finallist is a parameter. You need to pass an argument to your method, which, if an identifier instead of a constant (in your case, an identifier named 'finallist'), needs to be defined first!

Answer (score 3):

**Please read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)** in particular, [the section about classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

You will find tons of great OO Python tutorials online, like [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/python-from-scratch-object-oriented-programming/) or [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm).

#### Getting the return value of a function

```
 return_value = my_function(my_argument)
```

For example, using the interpreter by running python on the command line:

```
➤ python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Jul 20 2012, 22:15:08) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def square(x):
...     return x*x
... 
>>> four_squared = square(4)
>>> four_squared
16
```

#### Cleaning up the code:

Your code doesn't make sense.

1. What is `nmaidcount().finallist`?
2. Where do you define `finallist` in your program?
3. Why do you have `if True`? This will always be the case!

This is what I think you mean:

```
tsvs = glob.glob(sys.argv[1])

class StatFind:
  # This is the instance initialiser. 
  def __init__(self,tsvs):
    self.tsvs=tsvs 

    # here we define every instance of StatFind to have an attribute
    # called 'finallist' which will be accessible by all methods
    self.finallist = [] 

    # We do our initialisation here, when we initialise our object,
    # instead of in a separate method.
    for path in self.tsvs:
      finalist.append(do_something(path))

  def inserttomongo(self): 
    # The 'self' parameter is automagically set up by python to 
    # refer to the instance when 'insertmongo()' is called on an instance
    # for example, myInstance.insertmongo(), in which case 
    # self will be 'myInstance'
    mongo=pymongo.Connection('localhost')
    mongo_db=mongo['sample']
    mongo_collection=mongo_db['users']

    for dictvalue in self.finallist: 
      insert_id=mongo_collection.insert(dictvalue)

s=StatFind(tsvs) #This will call __init__() behind the scenes.
s.inserttomongo()
```

Comment: Hi.  The process and appending to finallist is in another method.  nmaidcount is a typo, it was supposed to be ncount.  I still dont seem to get the solution.  Please help

Comment: @user1189851 it sounds like you're new to Python and to programming in general. The best advice I can give you (besides walking you through it myself) is to run the command line interpreter (`python` on the command line) and use it to go through a tutorial. You could also try [this online tutorial](http://www.learnstreet.com/lessons/study/python)

Comment: the idea is that functions can be replaced by their return values. for example, if you have a function `def foo(x): return x*x` then you can replace any call to this function by the result. for example: `my_variable = foo(4)` would be the same as `my_variable = 16`