# Can I put a method as the argument in the setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, setinterval, pacman

Preety straight forward question, though I can't find the answer anywhere
I tried these two ways:

```
setInterval(function(){object/*or this*/.method()},500)
```

and

```
setInterval('object/*or this*/.method()',500)
```

Comment: Your first sample will work fine, but you forgot to invoke method with `()`.

Comment: What you mean under *"put a method as the parameter"*, maybe you should read this at first [What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter) and then [Window.setInterval MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setInterval in fact expects a method as the first argument, though there is an alternative syntax where the first argument can be a string of code (not recommended by most)

If you're having issues with that code, it may have to do with the scope of 'this'

```
setInterval(function(){this.method()},500)
```

In the above code, 'this' will refer to the closure itself, and wouldn't be the same as 'this.method' occurring outside of that closure. For example, the following would work:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.thingy = 'yep this is a thingy'
}
var myClass = new MyClass()

// Will log 'MyClass yep this is a thingy'
setInterval(function() { console.log('MyClass', myClass.thingy) }, 1000)
```

Whereas the following will not work (presuming instantiating the object and calling foo()):

```
function MyOtherClass() {
    this.thingy = 'also a thingy'
}

// Will log 'MyOtherClass undefined'
MyOtherClass.prototype.foo = function() {
    setInterval(function() { console.log('MyOtherClass', this.thingy) }, 1000)
}
```

The second example will work if we get around using 'this' within the closure (presuming instantiating the object and calling bar()):

```
MyOtherClass.prototype.bar = function() {
    var that = this
    setInterval(function() { console.log('MyOtherClass', that.thingy) }, 1000)
}
```

Also be sure that setInterval is being passed the name of a function:

```
setInterval(someFunction, 500)
```

rather than executing a function as an argument

```
setInterval(someFunction(), 500)
```

This last line of code is usually a mistake, unless someFunction() returns a function itself ;)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your 2 ways for passing a function to `setInterval` is whether you want to pass your function as refrence of just copy of it. Allow me to explain it by example:

## -1 Referring([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/9AmFL/)):

```
var obj = {
    testMethod: function () {
        console.log('function (testMethod): intial output');
    }
}
setInterval(function () {
    obj.testMethod()
}, 1000);
obj.testMethod = function () {
    console.log('function (testMethod): changed output');
}
```

when you run this code, the result 'll be execution of the modified version of `testMethod`. Because here you dont copy the function! Instead, you refer to it. So whenever function implementation is changed, the last modified version is executed.

## -2 Copying([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/9AmFL/1/)):

```
var obj = {
    testMethod: function () {
        console.log('function (testMethod): intial output');
    }
}
setInterval(obj.testMethod, 1000);
obj.testMethod = function () {
    console.log('function (testMethod): changed output');
}
```

Here all you do is you are passing a ***copy*** of the last defined version of the function `testMethod` to `setInterval`. So whatever changes you do to `testMethod`, the result of `setInterval` will not be changed.

Comment: I believe that second way is passing function by reference and first it's just executing function as method of `obj` Object.

Comment: if you can prove it by examples then you right .. check out [this Article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)

Comment: In javascript functions are object, so you copy reference value from `obj.testMethod` and not a function itself. `obj.testMethod` contained reference value from first function before you override it with new anonymous function expression. Look at [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/4V5Pu/) and read artciles : [References and Values](http://yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/references.html), [Reference type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_type), [Value type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type)

Comment: And quirks is out of date so would be better if read artciles from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and another article about Rvalues and Lvalues [Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science))