# Make a Dictionary method argument default to an empty dictionary instead of null

Tags: c#, dictionary, default

I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` as a method argument, and I was wondering if there is a way to make it default to an empty dictionary instead of `null`. I prefer to always have an empty list/dictionary/IEnumerable instead of `null`. I tried setting the parameter to:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = default(Dictionary<string,string>);
```

but that evaluates to `null`.

Is there some way to make the default Dictionary empty?

Comment: no you can't. default parameter's value should be a compile time constant if you are using optional parameters

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.. Why not just use `if (dictionary == null){ dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(); }` - the intention is clear, the caller doesn't mind, no extensions, no overridden behavior.. Why complicate things?

Comment: I changed "parameter" to "argument" btw, I *think* that is what you meant.. See [What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter) for the difference

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I guess I'll go with either the null check or the method overload.  The reason I even asked the question is that I agree whole-heartedly with this article (https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/07/02/stop-cheating-the-type-system) and this quote in it ("If you ever return a null IEnumerable instead of an empty one, I'm going to come to your house and shoot your face with a bazooka.") Null is the crappiest default that could exist, sigh...

Comment: The "default" value for any reference type is null. The default operator doesn't know how to construct object. What you're looking for is null-safety and doesn't exist in C#.

Answer (score 16):

> Is there some way to make the default Dictionary empty?

Yes, use the constructor instead of `default`:

```
void Foo(Dictionary<string, string> parameter){
    if(parameter == null) parameter = new Dictionary<string,string>();
}
```

You could also make the parameter optional:

```
void Foo(Dictionary<string, string> parameter = null)
{
    if(parameter == null) parameter = new Dictionary<string,string>();
}
```

An [optional parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264739(v=vs.100).aspx) must be a compile time constant, that's why you can't use `new Dictionary<string,string>()` directly.

---

According to the question if you can change the behaviour of the [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) keyword, no, you cannot return a different value. For reference types `null` is the default value and will be returned.

C# [language specs.](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) §12.2:

The default value of a variable depends on the type of the variable and is determined as follows:

- For a variable of a value-type, the default value is the same as the value computed by the value-type’s 
  default constructor (§11.1.2).
- For a variable of a reference-type, the **default value is null**.

**Update**: for what it's woth, you could use this extension (i wouldn't use it):

```
public static T EmptyIfNull<T>(this T coll) 
    where T :  ICollection, new() // <-- Constrain to types with a default constructor and collections
{
    if(coll == null)
        return new T();
    return coll;
}
```

Now you could use it in this way:

```
Dictionary<string, string> parameter = null;
Foo(parameter.EmptyIfNull());  // now an empty dictionary is passed
```

But the last thing another programmer wants to see is thousands of lines of code peppered with `.EmptyIfNull()` everywhere just because the first guy was too lazy to use a constructor.

Comment: i would combine this with the null coalescing operator.

Comment: @DanielA.White And I wouldn't. Why would you? What's in this answer is very easy to read. `parameter = parameter ?? new Dictionary<string,string>();` redundantly reassigns `parameter`'s prior value to itself, leaving the reader to wonder why that is happening.

Comment: Note though that since the OP is interested in making `Foo()` work, this needs a `Foo(Dictionary<string, string> parameter = null)` default value in addition to the parameter check inside the function body, instead of replaced by the parameter check inside the function body.

Comment: @hvd: i've provided another way to make `Foo` "work" without changing the dictionary in the method-body.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Like you, I wouldn't use that. :) I do not think that is what the OP is after, though: the OP is asking for a default, so the caller would not be specifying any parameter value. Your `EmptyIfNull` would force the caller to write `default(Dictionary<string, string>).EmptyIfNull()` or add a local otherwise-unused variable. But perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question. I've posted a different answer based on my own understanding of the question.

Comment: @hvd: you're right, it's not changing the behaviour of `default`(which is not possible). It's just another way to work around the issue which i don't see as a problem at all.

Comment: @AndyT It's too bad that such a good idea as `default` is crippled by being limited to 2 damn branches! I would love to be able to say, in my app, `default(IEnumerable<T>) = new IEnumerable<T>()`. The sun would be brighter, and the world a better place.

Comment: @Nostradamnit: No, it wouldn't be. Consider serialisation for persistence which uses `default` to minimise the size of data that should be stored (all `default` values are not stored to save space). Then you or your teammate changes the semantic of `default` and now you can throw your saved data thru the window because it's not backward compatible anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Thinking about it, the simple approach with any parameter that you want to give a default value that isn't a compile-time constant works here: do not give it a default value. Use an overloaded function instead.

```
public void Foo() {
  Foo(new Dictionary<string, string>());
}

public void Foo(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary) {
  ...
}
```

For the caller, it doesn't really matter how this is implemented: all that matters is that a call `Foo()` compiles and at run-time has exactly the same effect as `Foo(new Dictionary<string, string>())`, right? Well, exactly that is what's achieved by adding an overload.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like :

Classic implementation

```
public void Foo(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
    if (dictionary == null)
    {
        dictionary = Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToDictionary(_ => string.Empty);
    }
}
```

If you are using C# 8.0 and above

```
public void Foo2(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
    dictionary ??= Enumerable.Empty<string>().ToDictionary(_ => string.Empty);
}
```