# What is the order of destruction of function parameters?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, language-lawyer, object-lifetime

*This is a follow-up to my previous question [What is the order of destruction of function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36992039/3919155) because I accidentally confused arguments with parameters. Thanks to Columbo and T.C. for clearing me of terminology confusion in the comments of that question.*

If the body of some function `f` with parameters `p_1`, ..., `p_n` of types `T_1`, ..., `T_n` respectively throws an exception, finishes or returns, in what order are the parameters destroyed and why? Please provide a reference to the standard, if possible.

Examples:

```
template <typename ... Args>
void f(Args ... params) {} // in what order are params destroyed?

void f(T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3) {} // in what order are p1, p2 and p3 destroyed?
```

Comment: I don't think throwing an exception makes a big difference in regards of the evaluation order.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exact point in time at which parameters are destroyed is [unspecified](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1880):

> CWG decided to make it unspecified whether parameter objects are destroyed immediately following the call or at the end of the full-expression to which the call belongs.

The order in which parameters are constructed is unspecified as well, but because function parameters have block scope, although their order of construction is unspecified, **destruction is in the reverse order of construction**. E.g. consider

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int i;
    A(int i) : i(i) {std::cout << i;}
    ~A() {std::cout << '~' << i;} 
};

void f(A, A) {}

int main() {
    (f(0, 1), std::cout << "#");
}
```

prints `10#~0~1` [with GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4cdf10065c0f8a46) and `01#~1~0` with [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44f2a9b879b9862a); they construct parameters in different orders, but both destroy in the reverse order of construction, at the end of the full-expression the call occurs in (rather than right after returning to the caller). [VC++ prints `10~0~1#`](http://rextester.com/KNEXY30811).

Comment: Is there any requirement that destruction order is the reverse of construction order?

Comment: @M.M I imagine even if there wasn't, it would be implicitly necessary since otherwise it could easily mess up stuff with RAII, like cause a deadlock with two locks being held and not released in the proper order.

Comment: @M.M That probably is the case in practice. However, parameters do not have automatic storage duration and aren't temporaries, so I can't find any formal statement (and I don't see why it would be helpful).

Comment: @M.M It makes sense that there should be since there might be dependencies between the objects, so they should be destroyed in the reverse order as they were allocated.

Comment: "parameters do not have automatic storage duration" huh?

Comment: @M.M Note that it is also possible to introduce dependencies between the parameters **after** their construction, during the execution of the body. Generally, this might not be sensible, but... maybe it turns out to be practical in some cases.

Comment: @T.C. AFAICS automatic storage duration is defined as what block scope variables can have, which parameters aren't.

Comment: @Columbo Hmm...scope of function parameters are covered under [basic.scope.block] and other places of the standard clearly considers them automatic (e.g., [class.copy]/31-32).

Comment: @T.C. Just another oddity I guess. Anyway, adjusted the answer.

Comment: To make sure life is never dull, MSVC prints `10~0~1#` (the destructors are called from within `f`).

Comment: Does this CWG resolution appear in any standard or draft?

Comment: @M.M The current status is "drafting", so appropriate wording is currently being drafted.

Comment: @nikaza, if the order of construction or destruction is not defined, it is then impossible to set dependencies.

Comment: Update: the C++17 standard ended up making the point of destruction 
 (return versus full-expression) *implementation-defined*, not *unspecified*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39824814/sequencing-of-function-parameter-destruction