# Destructor of a function argument being called differently in gcc and MSVC

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, visual-studio-2015

While porting some C++ code from Microsoft Visual Studio to gcc, I ran into a weird bug, which I eventually boiled down to this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    int data;
    Foo(int i) : data(i) 
    {
        cout << "Foo constructed with " << i << endl; 
    }
    Foo(const Foo& f) : data(f.data)
    {
        cout << "copy ctor " << endl;
    }
    Foo(const Foo&& f) : data(f.data)
    {
        cout << "move ctor" << endl;
    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        cout << "Foo destructed with " << data << endl;
    }
};

int Bar(Foo f)
{
    cout << "f.data = " << f.data << endl;
    return f.data * 2;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f1(10);
    Foo f2(Bar(std::move(f1)));
}
```

If I compile and run the above code with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community, I get the following output:

```
Foo constructed with 10
move ctor
f.data = 10
Foo destructed with 10
Foo constructed with 20
Foo destructed with 20
Foo destructed with 10
```

However, if I compile and run the code with gcc 6.1.1 and --std=c++14, I get this output:

```
Foo constructed with 10
move ctor
f.data = 10
Foo constructed with 20
Foo destructed with 10
Foo destructed with 20
Foo destructed with 10
```

gcc calls the destructor of `f`, the argument to `Bar()`, after `Bar()` returns, while msvc calls the destructor (apparently) before it returns, or at least before the constructor of `f2`. When is `f` supposed to be destructed, according to the C++ standard?

Comment: `f`, being a named argument of `Bar()`, is not a temporary. In fact, I don't see any temporary. The other two `Foo`s are named f1 and f2. Not sure if there's an actual question here.

Comment: I 'm probably confused about what a temporary is. My question is when is the argument `f` of `Bar()` supposed to be destructed, and which implementation, msvc or gcc, is correct?

Comment: @MSalters I don't see how this is a duplicate of that question. That is about the order of construction/destruction in `f(a, b, c)` but this question never calls a function with more than 1 argument

Comment: @M.M: Check the answer as well. This question is a simpler version of the more general problem in the linked question.

Comment: This comment on the duplicate is relevant; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992569/what-is-the-order-of-destruction-of-function-parameters#comment61627914_36992615

Comment: OK, so the answer to this question is that in C++14 the `f` in `Bar(Foo f)` must be destroyed before `f2` is constructed (so g++ is wrong), however CWG decided to change this (perhaps in response to compilers getting it wrong).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are all right; it depends. It seems underspecified in the standard.

From [[expr.call]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#4) (this wording goes back to C++98);

> The lifetime of a parameter ends when the function in which it is defined returns. The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the calling function.

And the [CWG#1880](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1880);

> WG decided to make it unspecified whether parameter objects are destroyed immediately following the call or at the end of the full-expression to which the call belongs.

Both the behaviour of g++ (and clang) and MSVC would be correct, implementations are free to pick one approach over the other.

That all said, if the code you have is dependent on this ordering, I would change it such that the ordering is more deterministic - as you have seen, it leads to subtle bugs.

---

A simplified example of this behaviour is;

```
#include <iostream>
struct Arg {
    Arg() {std::cout << 'c';}
    ~Arg() {std::cout << 'd';}
    Arg(Arg const&)  {std::cout << 'a';}
    Arg(Arg&&)  {std::cout << 'b';}
    Arg& operator=(Arg const&)  {std::cout << 'e'; return *this;}
    Arg& operator=(Arg&&)  {std::cout << 'f'; return *this;}
};
void func(Arg) {}
int main() {
    (func(Arg{}), std::cout << 'X');
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Clang and g++ both produce `cXd` and MSVC produces `cdX`.