# C++11 order of member class initialization

Tags: c++, class, c++11, initialization

I have code:

```
struct testInit {
    testInit(int i1_) 
        : i1(i1_) {
        std::cout << "testInit::testInit" << std::endl;
    }

    int initI2() {
        std::cout << "testInit::initI2::i1: " << i1 << std::endl;
        return i1;
    }

    const int i1 = 1;
    const int i2 = initI2();

};

int main() {
    testInit ti(3);

    std::cout << "i1: " << ti.i1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "i2: " << ti.i2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**The output is:**

```
testInit::initI2::i1: 3
testInit::testInit
i1: 3
i2: 3
```

So, I am wondering what exactly is order of initialization of class members. I thought that the output should be i1: 3 and i2: 1 - which is obviously wrong - but why?

Comment: Variables are always initialized in their declaration order, so `i1` then `i2` in your code, no matter how you initialize them. Your constructor is equivalent to `testInit(int _i1) : i1(_i1), i2(initI2()) { }`.

Comment: "I thought that the output should be..." why?

Answer (score 4):

> I am wondering what exactly is order of initialization of class members

Members are always [initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order) in order of declaration in the class definition, so `i1` will be initialized at first, then `i2`.

> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.

And for `testInit::testInit(int)`, both member initializer list and [default member initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) are specified on `i1`; the default member initializer will be ignored.

> If a member has a default member initializer and also appears in the member initialization list in a constructor, the default member initializer is ignored.

Then for `testInit ti(3);`, `i1` is initialized with `3` via member initializer list firstly, then `i2` is initialized with `initI2()` via default member initializer, then it'll be `3` too.

Comment: quite amazing you've answered the same question about default and mem-initializer with const.

Comment: @codekaizer They're not same; I think the point of this question is the initialization order (and the mix of member initializer list and default member initializer makes it complex), isn't it?

Comment: true. i mean some elements are the same. but the real question is about the initialization order. you've enlightened me with this one.

Comment: thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 2):

From [dcl.init.list#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.list#4)

> Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the
>   initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack expansions,
>   **are evaluated in the order in which they appear**. That is, every value
>   computation and side effect associated with a given initializer-clause
>   is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated
>   with any initializer-clause that follows it in the comma-separated
>   list of the initializer-list.

which for your case is:

```
testInit ti(3); // replaces the default initialization of i1 using the mem-initializer
```

then `i2` is default initialized to `3` using `initI2()` for `i1` is already `3` by this time (i.e. `testInit` is already well-defined).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of citing the standard - which is already done by another answer - I'm giving you some empirical data:

```
#include <iostream>

struct testInit {
    testInit(int i1_) 
        : i1(i1_) {
        std::cout << "testInit::testInit" << std::endl;
    }

    int initI2() {
        std::cout << "testInit::initI2::i1: " << i1 << std::endl;
        return i1;
    }

    const int i2 = initI2();
    const int i1 = 1;
};

int main() {
    testInit ti(3);

    std::cout << "i1: " << ti.i1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "i2: " << ti.i2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
testInit::initI2::i1: 0
testInit::testInit
i1: 3
i2: 0
```

Experimenting around like this is *of course* by no means "enough" to be sure about some behaviour of C++, simply because you can easily run into undefined behaviour (which the above code actually has) or implementation defined behaviour.

*But nonetheless: Just experiment a bit. It won't hurt and you're probably going to remember far better what you've "discovered" vs what you've read somewhere.*

undefined behaviour due to the access to the uninitialized `i1`)

Comment: maybe it will be useful why the output is like that.

Comment: @codekaizer that's not the point of my answer. It's answered clearly in the (now available) other answers, after all. My answer hints that experimenting a bit would've given the answer faster than asking here ... and would probably be remembered better than after reading a passage from the standard.

Comment: What if the order of initialization was *implementation defined*? This would give you the behaviour on just one platform/compiler. Consider the same question about the [order of destruction of function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992039/what-is-the-order-of-destruction-of-function-arguments).

Comment: I wouldn't suggest experimenting with C++ is enough. It's tremendously unfortunate, but there are enough UB/unspecified/implementation-defined stuff that wrecks you.

Comment: @passerby of course I do **not** mean that one should stop after experimenting nor that it's "enough". It's just better to learn stuff while doing vs just reading about it. Edited my answer to state this clearly.