# How do rand/srand functions work in C

Tags: c, function, random, types

I'm trying to understand how do `rand` and `srand` functions work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int seed;
    printf("please type in new seed:\n");
    scanf("%i", &seed);
    void srand(unsigned int seed);
    int rand(void);
    printf("%i\n", rand);   
    return 0;
}
```

But my compiler says:

> format `%i` expects argument of type `int`, but argument 2 has type `int (*)(void) [-Wformat=]   printf("%i\n", rand);`

Where is the mistake?

Comment: The error is unrelated to both `rand` and `srand`...

Comment: You're confusing functions with variables.

Comment: And you're using the syntax for declaring functions when you want to *call* the function.

Comment: Your confusing languages.  Your title says C language but your tags are C++.  Which language?  The C++ has functions that improve the randomness, which C doesn't.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: Please remain civil in the comments. [Be Nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some basic syntax misunderstandings. When you write:

```
void srand(unsigned int seed);
int rand(void);
```

those are *declarations* of the functions, it doesn't call the functions. To call a function, you don't include the parameter and return types, you just put the arguments (if needed) inside the `()`:

```
srand(seed);
```

Then you print the result with:

```
printf("%d\n", rand());
```

The `()` after `rand` means to call the function; the value it returns will be passed to `printf()`. Since you left this out, your code tried to pass the function pointer itself to `printf()`, rather than the value it returns.

Comment: You got "parameter" and "argument" the wrong way round :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB I can never remember which is which.

Comment: Think "default argument", that gives you a reliable clue. Or "vaargs -- variable arguments". Or "argument-dependent lookup" if you're playing for the winning team.

Comment: @KerrekSB Doesn't help, I can also think "default parameter".

Comment: Ironically, your very last sentence makes mockery of itself: You try to pass the function pointer to `printf`, not to `printf()`! The latter is an `int`.

Comment: Don't think that! :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/156859/1491895

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help you (or lesser beings) get a clear head about programming. It's best to think that "parameters are part of the function", and "arguments are part of the call".

Comment: @KerrekSB My writing style is to put `()` after a name to indicate that it names a function.

Comment: @Barmar: That's ungood. Think about `typedef void F(int);` and `F * f(...);`. It's a big difference whether you pass `5` to `f` or to `f()`!

Comment: @KerrekSB When higher-order functions aree involved, I'll use more descriptive language like "The function returned by f()`.

Answer (score -2):

You pass function instead of an integer... try:

```
printf("%i\n", rand());
```