# Javascript - about nested parentheses/parameters

Tags: javascript

I have a question about *line 5* of this little Javascript program. With the parentheses/parameters on *line 5*, `audioNumber` is inside/next to the inner parentheses because `audioNumber` is a parameter of `.indexOf`. Whereas the number `1` on this line is a parameter of `.splice` so it is inside the outer parentheses. Is this a correct understanding of why `audioNumber` and `1` are where they are on *line 5*?

```
function playAudio(audioNumber) {
  var audio = document.getElementById('sound' + audioNumber);
  audio.play();
  var nonPlaying = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  nonPlaying.splice(notPlaying.indexOf(audioNumber), 1); // line 5
  nonPlaying.forEach(function(id) {
    document.getElementById('sound' + id).pause();
    document.getElementById('sound' + id).currentTime = 0;
  });
};
```

Comment: Yes that is a correct understanding

Comment: Strictly speaking, those are arguments, not parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The splice method can be used with 2 parameters: the start index and the number of elements to delete:

```
array.splice(start, deleteCount)
```

The 'audioNumber' is the parameter of the indexOf method:

```
notPlaying.indexOf(audioNumber)
```

...the result returned by the indexOf method is the first parameter (the 'start' parameter) in the splice method whereas the value '1' is the second parameter in the splice method (the 'deleteCount' parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's right! but one slight difference these are arguments not parameters.