# Expand object literal as html5 data- attributes

Tags: javascript

It is possible to expands an object literal as html5 data- attributes?

Having the following object:

```
const requirements = {
    'data-description': 'some text...',
    'data-pointer': true,
    'data-speaker': true
}
```

I would like to expand it in a anchor tag in order to get something like this:

```
<a href="#" class="show-modal" data-description="some-text" data-pointer="true" data-speaker="true">Show modal</a>
```

I tried to use the spread syntax in this way `` <a href="#" class="show-modal" `${...requirements}`>Show modal</a> `` But nothing get printed

I am now depending on this function that builds an anchor and passes the data dynamically.

```
function buildAnchor(requirements) {
    const anchor = document.createElement('a');

    anchor.setAttribute('class', 'show-modal');
    anchor.setAttribute('href', '#');
    anchor.textContent = 'More info';

    Object.keys(requirements).forEach(data => {
        anchor.setAttribute(data, requirements[data]);
    });

    return anchor.outerHTML;
}
```

This function do the job, but i would like to know if it's possible to use spread syntax

Thanks in advance

Comment: Spread is for arrays. You have an object.

Comment: It is also possible in objects as i can read in mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Yes, but for your usage (a function that builds the element), you need an array. See my answer below.

Comment: @user615274: Please clarify, are you saying that the only thing that matters about the question is the ability to use *spread syntax*, or are you saying that you simply want a nice, short, clean solution?

Comment: ...the title ***Expand object literal as html5 data- attributes*** sure seems to give a clear summary that you actually care about a real-world solution to a real-world problem, but I guess this is still a burning question for some...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about straightforwardly using an [`HTMLElement`'s `dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) and then assigning a simplified configuration object to it via `Object.assign` ... like ...

```js
var requirements = {
  'description': 'some text...',
  'pointer': true,
  'speaker': true
};
var elmLink = document.createElement('a');

elmLink.href = '';
Object.assign(elmLink.dataset, requirements);

console.log('elmLink : ', elmLink);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This answer works, but avoids the entire point of the question, which was to use the spread syntax.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ... the OP's question and also the title that was chosen do state something else ... is it "... possible to expands an object literal as html5 data- attributes?"

Comment: And yet, the last line of the question is: *This function do the job, but i would like to know if it's possible to **use spread syntax***.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `data-*` attribute as a single `JSON` string, then use `JSON.parse()` to create a JavaScript object representation of the `.dataset` property.

Note the single quote surrounding attribute value within template literal that surrounds valid `JSON` at HTML string.

```js
const requirements = {
    'description': 'some text...',
    'pointer': true,
    'speaker': true
}

const a = `<a data-requirements='${JSON.stringify(requirements)}'>click</a>`;

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", a);

let data = JSON.parse(document.querySelector("a").dataset.requirements);
           
console.log(data, data.description, data.pointer, data.speaker);
```

Answer (score 0):

The spread syntax won't do what you want. That's really for including key/value pairs from one object into another, or for destructuring assignment.

You can use `Object.entries()` with `.map()` and `.join()` inside a template literal.

```js
const requirements = {
  'data-description': 'some text...',
  'data-pointer': true,
  'data-speaker': true
};
const s = `<a href="#" class="show-modal" ${Object.entries(requirements).map(([k, v]) => k + "='" + v + "'").join(" ")}>Show modal</a>`;

console.log(s);
```

---

I think it would be cleaner to move the attribute creation into its own function.

```js
const requirements = {
  'data-description': 'some text...',
  'data-pointer': true,
  'data-speaker': true
};
const s = `<a href="#" class="show-modal" ${oToA(requirements)}>Show modal</a>`;

console.log(s);

function oToA(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
               .map(([k, v]) => k + "='" + v + "'")
               .join(" ")
}
```

You could enhance the function by replacing embedded quotes with HTML entities.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: He's asking about using it with his existing data structure. Sure *you* can change his requirements, but that doesn't mean *he* can change his requirements.

Answer (score 0):

From **[MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)**

> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression to be
>   expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls)
>   or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression
>   to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for
>   object literals) are expected.

Since you are trying to build a function that takes in the requirements as arguments (not key/value pairs), an array structure would make better sense than an object structure.

```js
const requirements = [
    {'data-description': 'some text...'},
    {'data-pointer': true},
    {'data-speaker': true}
];

(function populate(){
  var anchor = document.createElement("a");
  // Convert the arguments object to an array and enumerate it
  // so that each object key can become an attribute and the 
  // corresponding value can become the value:
  Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).forEach(function(arg){
    for(var prop in arg){
      anchor.setAttribute(prop, arg[prop]);
    }
  });
  console.log(anchor);
})(...requirements);
```

Comment: It is wrong to say that spread is just for arrays. It's for object literals to as described in your own docs link. Also, it avoids the point of the question, which is to work with the existing data structure.

Comment: @guest271314: At that point it is actually spread, because it's taking an existing collection, and "spreading" them into another collection. Rest is where you're receiving the "rest" (remainder) of the arguments. So "spread" sends a list of items, and "rest" receives them. Though he *could* use "rest" syntax in the function parameter. `function populate(...args) {`, thereby avoiding the need for `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).forEach(...`, since `args` would be an actual Array.

Comment: @llama Appears to be rest element syntax at Answer, where `...` is used at last (only) parameter to funtion

Comment: @guest271314: But it's in the function call. Conceptually, it's the same as using `...` to include items into a new array. Like: `var newArr = [1, 2, ...oldArray];` Directionally, the content of an existing collection is being spread out into a new collection.

Comment: @llama Are you suggesting that `(function fn() {})(...arr)` is different from `function fn(...arr){}`?

Comment: @guest271314: Yes. ;-) The first example you give is taking an array and spreading them into the call of the function (into its parameters or arguments object). The second example is defining a parameter that takes the rest of the arguments passed (which in that case is all the arguments) and puts them into the `arr` array.

Comment: @llama Either pattern provides same results. `...` used at function parameter is rest parameter. Described the syntax as rest element at previous comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632795/expand-object-literal-as-html5-data-attributes/46632997?noredirect=1#comment80216913_46632993, which is not accurate.

Comment: @guest271314: The results are certainly related, but the difference is in where the `...` is used. Notice in the docs for the spread syntax, that all the `...` examples are taking an existing collection, and inserting its members into a new collection. That's equivalent to having the `...` at the call of a function. `foo(...arr)`. Whereas having the `...` at the *definition* of the function parameter states that any remaining arguments should be added to a *new* Array. It's subtle distinction, but still a distinction.

Comment: @llama When `...` is used before the last parameter passed to a function call the appropriate description is rest parameter, see [What is SpreadElement in ECMAScript documentation? Is it the same as Spread operator at MDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37151966/)

Comment: @guest271314: Yes, that's what I'm saying. But in this answer, the `...` is not used to define a parameter; it's used to *call* the IIFE function. The `(...requrements)` at the end is the same as doing `foo(...requirements)` if the function had been named `foo`.

Comment: @llama _"the `...` is not used to define a parameter"_ ? _"it's used to call the IIFE function"_ with the parameter `...requirements`

Comment: @guest271314: The `...requirements` isn't a parameter. It's an Array that was created above the IIFE, so they're being passed as arguments. Remember, "parameters" are in a function *definition*, whereas "arguments" are in a function *call*.

Comment: ...Here's a related Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter

Comment: @llama Why is `...requirements` not a declaration? `...requirements` is declared as the value to be passed to the function call, yes?

Comment: @guest271314: Because it's not defining any new identifiers. It's just passing existing data to the function. Using the spread syntax, it's basically equivalent to doing `foo(requirements[0], requirements[1], requirements[2])`, except in an IIFE instead of a function named `foo`.