# Clarification required - Passing arguements to functions - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a doubt regarding one of the answers at this link

[Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)

I am providing the particular answer that I need clarification on:

> An ambiguous case that breaks in the absence of a semicolon:
>
> ```
> // define a function
> var fn = function () {
>     //...
> } // semicolon missing at this line
>
> // then execute some code inside a closure
> (function () {
>     //...
> })();
> ```
>
> This will be interpreted as:
>
> ```
> var fn = function () {
>     //...
> }(function () {
>     //...
> })();
> ```
>
> We end up passing the second function as an argument to the first
>   function and then trying to call the result of the first function call
>   as a function. The second function will fail with a "... is not a
>   function" error at runtime.

My doubt is that how come the second function became the argument of the first function?  Because for all I know

```
function myFunc(/*argument goes here*/){}
```

And not after the `{}`.

Can someone explicitly explain which ones are the functions and their respective arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up the parameters in the definition of the function and the arguments passed in when the function is called. The parameters *do* go in the first parenthesis when you define the function, but arguments go in the second when you *call* it.

for example:

```js
let test = function(arg){               // define parameters here
       console.log("called with", arg)  // use arguments here
}
("hello")                               //pass in arguments here
```

The confusion might be caused by using the term "arguments" for two related but slightly different things:

- Parameters that are specified in the definition of a function.
- Arguments that are passed when a function is called.

Since these things are related, people sometimes refer to these two different concepts using the same word sometimes parameters, sometimes arguments. The difference is better explained here: [What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

What OP of the answer means is that when you minify your javascript file, if a function is followed by IIFE without having semicolon between them, it will break.

Now to answer your question:

> how come the second function became the argument of the first function?

how do you call a function? You add parenthesis`()` after it.

In the mentioned case, the code would look like:

```js
var fn = function () { ... }(function () { ... })();

// i.e.

var fn = function() { ... }(...)();
```

So it calls the function and expects another functions its output.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any function directly by putting `()` behind it. Just like you call a method. `myMethod( arguments )`.

So if you write a function definition and then add `()` to the end, it immediately gets called:

```js
var fn = function() {
  console.log( 'function executing' );
}();
```

When you call a function, anything between the `()` will be interpreted as an argument for the function. And since functions can be arguments for other functions, omitting that one `;`, makes the second function become the argument of the first.

Such directly called functions are called IIFE: `Immediately Invoked Function Expression`.

So the following two lines are identical in result:

```js
var first = function( arg ) {
  console.log( "arg: " + arg );
}( "first argument" );

var second = function( arg ) {
  console.log( "arg: " + arg );
};
second( "first argument" );
```

The difference between the two is that function first gets called immediately by adding the `()` after the definition. And the function second gets called seperately on the next line.

To make a bigger distinction between IIFE functions, they are usually wrapped into an extra set of `()` to make it more clear that it's a IIFE:

`(function(){ ... })( arg );` or even more clear `(function(){ ... }( arg ));`.

Answer (score 0):

As you many know writing an `IIFE` like this doesn't work since for a function to be evaluated as an expression it requires extra parentheses

```
function foo() {

}();
```

instead it needs to be this

```
(function foo() {

})();
```

Well this is not the case when you have already made it an expression by assigning it to a variable like this

```
let foo = function foo() {

}();
```

Now as soon as you write a function like the last example but omit the `;` then you can fall into the trap of running the first function passing in the second function as you showed in your example.

```
let foo = function foo() {
    //...
}(function () {
    //...
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the function on line 1 is **function expression** and not **function declaration**. A function expression followed by a pair of parentheses will be invoked immediately (also known a IIFEs). So, the following code would log *Hello World* :

`var fn = function(a){
        console.log(a)
}("Hello World");`

In your code, the 2nd function is being passed to first function but it's reference is not being stored in any formal parameter.