# PHP meta default parameter

Tags: php, parameters, default

With the code:

```
function basic($test='David') {
    return "Test='".$test."';";
}

function using($test) {
    return basic($test);
}

echo using();
```

Suppose I din't create the function `basic` but I wanna propagate the default parameter 
[mind the difference between parameter and argument: [What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter]) ]

In English: say `basic` is encapsulated, I don't know of the default value `'David'` but I wanna be able to call `using` without passing an argument. But the output to be `David`; if you feel me?

But hey without mentioning `David` in the `using` function. I thought `null` value will do it or as blank as I did in the code sample.

My question is: is there a [default] value that represent the absence of the argument so that the default is in effect for a remote function that you don't know it's default value?

This question is simple but what of a complex function that you can't trace the processing of the argument to derive [~suggest] it's default. How can we have a pronoun default? -If you get me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function using($test = null) {
    if(!$test)
        return $this->basic();
    return $this->basic($test);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to accept this as an answer unless it is the ultimate solution.
I was hoping for a value or class or type without my own logic [if - statement] to delegate [~meta] the default.

Comment: I accepted it, just as I feel it is the most real solution but I believe in an ideal ultimate solution. So if you come across, do share..!? Thanks as of yet and in advance.