# Why did people choose "argument" as the term to describe the value of a parameter?

Tags: computer-science

I know the difference between parameter and argument.

1. Parameter is variable in the declaration of function.
2. Argument is the actual value of this variable that gets passed to function.

[image]

From the dictionary, argument means *"a discussion or debate in which a number of people put forward different or opposing opinions"*.

It's very hard for me to bridge *"debate"*/disagree to value of parameters (I am not a English native speaker). Are they related? In computer science, why did people choose "argument" as the term to describe the value of parameter?

### Related Questions

1. [What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter)
2. [Wikipedia: Parameter (Computer Science)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming))

Comment: `From the dictionary, argument means a discussion or debate in which a number of people put forward different or opposing opinions.` - please see https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/argument.

Comment: It's coming from the mathematic and not from the linguistic.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144141/what-is-the-sense-of-using-word-argument-for-inputs-of-a-function

Comment: There is more than one meaning of *argument*: **2** a reason or set of reasons given in support of an idea, action or theory: *"there is a strong argument for submitting a formal appeal"* | [with clause] : *"he rejected the argument that keeping the facility would be costly."* – That is pretty close to the use of *passing an argument to a function.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Argument* has been used in that sense as a technical term in English in the fields of astronomy and mathematics for 600 years, and later also in logic and computer science. But as a technical sense, it may well be missing from your L2 dictionary.

You are asking what the relationship is between that sense and the everyday sense of *loud disagreement*. That is a question about etymology, not computing. Most native English speakers will be unlikely to know the answer, without first consulting a historical dictionary of English. And even then, the big OED doesn't yield a very clear-cut answer.

It is all so very long ago that it is hard to tell.