# function with 2 parameters without value

Tags: c++

Is this function have any sense? if I didn't define the value of p_var1[] and p_size?

Just to know if it make sense, I have bigger code, but as a beginner, for me, if there is no values for these variables, that is weird.

First function:

```
int max1(int p_values[15][15])
{
    int max_value;
    for(int i=0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        int max_v = fnc(p_values[i], 15);
        if( max_value < max_v)
        {
            max_value = max_v;
        }
    }
    return max_value;

}
```

and second

```
//p_var1[] - is an array of values
//p_size - is the size of array
int fnc(int p_var1[], int p_size)
{
    int max_value;
    for (int i = 0; i < p_size; i++)
    {
        if (max_value > p_var1[i])
        {
            max_value = p_var[i];
        }
    }
    return max_value;


}
```

Comment: You have to define the values when calling the function, or you can set the default ones in the definition.

Comment: so, if there is no values in this one, the function is non sense?

Comment: no, it's not. When you call the function from some other part of code, it will be executed.

Comment: In your code, `max_value` can be anything, you should go with `int max_value = p_var1[0]` and start the `for` loop with `int i = 1`.

Answer (score 2):

This code isn't a full program, it's just a function definition. Here, a function called `fnc` is declared that can be called with parameters. Here's an example of a full program using it:

```
//p_var1[] - is an array of values
//p_size - is the size of array
int fnc(int p_var1[], int p_size)
{
    int max_value;
    for (int i = 0; i < p_size; i++)
    {
        if (max_value > p_var1[i])
        {
            max_value = p_var[i];
        }
    }
    return max_value;


}

int main() {
    int lst[5] = {10, 2, 6, 4, 8};
    int max = fnc(lst, 5); // max = 10
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added first function, that call this one

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wrote `fnc(p_values[i], 15)` without knowing what it means? Not the best approach, but asking about it shows promise. When this expression is reached, the `fnc` identifier says that we're going to pause the execution of the current function (`max1`) and jump to execute the function `fnc`. Once that function finishes, the returned value will be the value of the expression and execution of `max1` can resume. The stuff in the parentheses says that as we jump to `fnc`, assign `p_var1 = p_values[i]` and `p_size = 15` (the first parameter is assigned the first argument, and the second parameter is assigned the second argument). If you're confused by the terms "parameter" and "argument", see [What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter)

So when you call `fnc` you **do** define the value of `p_var1` and `p_size` (for that function call). *(Wikipedia has [an article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)) with [an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Example) that covers this also, and you might find some useful information in the rest of that article.)*

Comment: I need to read again the chapter with Functions.. cause I didn't get it :(