# How to use the `dynamic` when specifying generic type arguments in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, casting, clr

How to use the `dynamic` when specifying generic type arguments in C#?

I am reading the **CLR via C#** book. And I come across the following paragraph:

> It is also possible to use dynamic when specifying generic type arguments to a generic class
>   (reference type), a structure (value type), an interface, a delegate, or a method. When you do this, the
>   compiler converts dynamic to Object and applies DynamicAttribute to the various pieces of
>   metadata where it makes sense. Note that the generic code that you are using has already been
>   compiled and will consider the type to be Object; no dynamic dispatch will be performed because the
>   compiler did not produce any payload code in the generic code.

As far as I understand this excerpt tells that I can use the `dynamic` as a type argument in (e.g.) a class definition. But after trying this out I come to a conclusion that it is no different from using any other placeholder in the type argument. So, I doubt that my understanding is correct.

```
using System;

namespace myprogram
{
    class A<dynamic> {
        public dynamic a;
    }

    class B {
        public Int32 b;
    }

    class C<T> {
        public T c;
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            //Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'myprogram.B' [Console.NET]csharp(CS0029)
            //A<B> a = new A<B> {a = "foo"};

            //Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'myprogram.B' [Console.NET]csharp(CS0029)
            //C<B> c = new C<B> {c = "foo"};

            //as you can see it does not matter if I use the T or dynamic, the effect is the same
            //so, what is the use of using the dynamic in the class definition?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `string` is not `A<B>` or `C<B>` and vice-versa. This is what the compiler is telling you and it's correct.

Comment: Read generics like this: `C<B>` `C` is a class that has code which depends on anything that satisfies the interface of `B`. Now it's clear why you cannot do what you're trying because `string` does not satisfy the interface of `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very important to understand the difference between type "arguments" and type "parameters".

Consider this:

```
class Foo<T> { } // "T" is a type parameter

...

Foo<int> f; // "int" is a type argument
```

Type parameters declare what types you can pass to this generic type/method. Type parameters are essentially identifiers, not an existing type. When you pass a type to a generic type/method, the type you passed is called the type argument. This is quite similar to [the difference between a method parameter and argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter).

So the excerpt is trying to say that given a generic type, you can pass the type `dynamic` to it, and it will be treated as `object` by the CLR. It doesn't mean that you can do this:

```
class A<dynamic> {

}
```

It means that you can do this:

```
var list = new List<dynamic>();
```

Or with the types declared in your code:

```
C<dynamic> c = new C<dynamic> {c = "foo"};
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for when writing the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: in your code `dynamic` is just a type parameter name, you're not actually passing an argument.

> As far as I understand this excerpt tells that I can use the dynamic as a type argument in (e.g.) a class definition.

There are no type *arguments* in a class definition. In the definition of a generic type there are type *parameters*. When you construct a generic type these are type arguments. So this:

```
class A<dynamic>
{
}

var a = new A<string>();
```

is a generic type with one type parameter whose name is `dynamic`. Then follows an instantiation of the type where `string` is passed as a type argument to the type parameter `dynamic`. This:

```
class A<T>
{
}

var a = new A<dynamic>();
```

is a generic type with one type parameter whose name is `T`. Then follows an instantiation of the type where `dynamic` is passed as a type argument to the type parameter `T`.

You're looking for the latter, not the former.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic as an Argument, so you can use

```
var c = new C<dynamic>();
```

But you cannot use a concrete Type, to build a generic Type, like

```
     class A<dynamic> { }
     class B<int> { }
```

In underline: This you should NOT do ! You are defining an argument name here !

Actually it doesn't cause compile-error, but the word "int" as treated as a parameter name, same as there would be T. It's a good paradigm to use names starting with T for generic type parameters, not to mix it up, with any type from the Rest of your program.

As you concluded yourself, your definition of A and C are completly identical,
except you are confused, cause the word dynamic has nothing to do with the type 
dynamic in this place.

If you want to assign a string, of course you have to create a `new C<string>()` or `new C<object>()` or any other type accepting a string.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was in reality masking an ExpandoObject as a dynamic, so I ended up using code like this:

```
static async Task<TReturn> GenericMethodAsync<TReturn()
{
    if (typeof(TReturn) == typeof(ExpandoObject))
        // Return an ExpandoObject
}
```

Which was then used by a method like this one

```
static async Task<dynamic> OtherMethodAsync()
{
    return await GenericMethodAsync<ExpandoObject>();
}
```