# what is the difference between parameters and arguments?

Tags: java, loops

I am doing an assignment for school and messing around with some different types of loops, namely for loops... I am curious as to whether the items it accepts are considered as parameters or arguments... and what is the actual difference between the two?

for (initialization; condition; increment/decrement) {
     Statement(s)
}

Comment: Your courseware should cover the difference between the two. If it does not, please ask your teacher to explain this in class because _everyone in your class_ should be told what the difference is. Not just you.

Comment: They are neither parameters nor arguments because `for` is not a function/method. They are expressions.

Comment: @jarmod they're not all expressions. Only the `Expression` is an expression; `ForInit` and `ForUpdate` are statements.

Comment: I understand how the idea can come up, but note, that `for(a;b;c){...}` uses `;` rather than `,`. Long ago I heard my profs talking about formal and actual parameters, may be a variation of the theme.

Comment: @AndyTurner OK, technically ForInit can be a list of statement expressions or a local variable declaration, and ForUpdate can be a list of statement expressions. Though the Java tutorial on `for` loosely calls all 3 expressions (per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html):

> **Parameters** refers to the list of variables in a method declaration.
>   **Arguments** are the actual values that are passed in when the method is
>   invoked. When you invoke a method, the arguments used must match the
>   declaration's parameters in type and order.

E.g. `moveCircle()` method has 3 *parameters* in declaration like: `circle`, `deltaX`, `deltaY`.

```
public void moveCircle(Circle circle, int deltaX, int deltaY) {
//...
}
```

E.g. `moveCircle()` method is invoked and has 3 *arguments*:

```
moveCircle(myCircle, 23, 56)
```

If we speak about loops, then we have [the general form of the for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) like:

```
for (initialization; termination;
     increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

Where is:

- The *initialization* expression initializes the loop; it's executed
  once, as the loop begins.
- When the *termination* expression evaluates
  to false, the loop terminates.
- The *increment* expression is invoked
  after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for
  this expression to increment or decrement a value.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter is a variable in a method definition. When a method is called, the arguments are the data you pass into the method's parameters.

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter)  to check further discussion.