# attribute and parameter - differences and using

Tags: python

What is the difference between when we use a variable as an attribute like `self.message` and when we use it as a parameter like `message` in a method:

```
def talk(self, message)
    print("{} sad : {}".format(self.name, self.message))

def talk(self, message)
    print("{} sad : {}".format(self.name, message))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea at all what you're trying to say. Also, your example code contains numerous typos.

Comment: I have seen it ,But i didn't find what i search

Comment: In general, "what's the difference" questions are not very useful. Usually, the two things don't actually have anything to do with each other, and so there are really two questions - "please explain the first thing" and "please explain the second thing". On Stack Overflow, you are only supposed to ask one question at a time, and we cannot just "explain" something to you because there is no way to know what needs explaining - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question .

Comment: ```self``` parameter is added to make the function an attribute of the class.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I have to completely disagree. Asking "What's the difference" is an excellent way of focusing the question and telling us exactly what aspect of the concepts the questioner doesn't understand. Asking "Please explain this thing", on the other hand, is completely open-ended and tells us nothing about what part they don't understand. Aside from the typos (which I fixed) this question is perfectly clear.

Comment: Let's see your answer to it, then.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: The question is currently closed, and is therefore not allowing answers. I would like to write an answer when it's reopened.

Comment: I voted to reopen, because I'd like to see you try to prove me wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

A parameter is really just a variable. It is declared by the function signature, and it gets assigned one of the arguments as part of the function call process.

An attribute is not a variable at all. It is a part of an object, similar to an index inside `[]`. It is accessed using dot notation.

In your code, both functions declare a `message` parameter, but only the second one uses it. The first function gets all its information from the `self` object instead of using its `message` parameter.