# Passing a method as a parameter to another method

Tags: python

This may be a newbie question but I was wondering if it is possible to pass a method as a parameter to another method and get the result back?

Example

```
 def with_price(price: float, factor: float = 2.0):
        return (price * factor)
    
 def a_method(a: float, with_price):
        b = with_price(11)
        return a * b
 print(a_method)
```

Then I get this

```
<function main.<locals>.a_method at 0x0000023B24029EE0>
```

which is not what I expect.

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: You're not *calling* `a_method`. You need parentheses for that (and you also need to provide its parameters). Also you have an indentation error that must have happened in pasting here.

Comment: It looks like the indenting is wrong and `def main` is missing. Please [edit] to fix it. See [mre].

Comment: Note, those arent methods

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Based on what you've written, it's not clear if you even need parameters, like maybe you just need to do `def a_method(...): b = with_price(11) ...`. Please [edit] to clarify. Be wary of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your snippet you are printing the function object `a_method`.

Passing a function as a parameter to another function is possible, but you need to actually call it if you want it to execute.

Considering your example:

1. Define a function `with_price`

```py
def with_price(price: float, factor: float = 2.0):
        return (price * factor)
```

2. Define the function `a_method`. Note how `myfunction` is a generic parameter, not the function we just defined:

```py
def a_method(a: float, myfunction):
        b = myfunction(11)
        return a * b
```

3. Finally, call `a_method`, passing `with_price` as parameter:

```py
print( a_method(2, with_price) )
```

Comment: Another great explanation. The keyword is parameter passed to function NOT function passed as function?

Answer (score 2):

`print(a_method)` is telling Python to print what `print_method` is, which is a function. However, you want it to print what the function returns when called, so you should have used `print(a_method())`, since calling the function looks like `a_method()`.

However, your code appears confused in a few more ways, so that's not even really the problem. Here's what I think you tried to do:

```
def with_price(price: float, factor: float = 2.0):
    return (price * factor)
    

def a_method(a: float, price_func):
    b = price_func(11)
    return a * b
    

print(a_method(5, with_price))
```

This calls `a_method`, with `a` set to `5` and `price_func` set to `with_price`. So, it computes `b` as `11 * 2.0`, which is `22` and then returns `5 * 22`, which is `110`.

Note that doing it like this will cause `factor` to always be `2.0` since you provide no way of passing another value.

Also, you named things 'methods', but they are really just functions. Methods are functions defined on an object, which expect the first parameter to be a reference to the object they are being called on. You could turn them into methods by adding something like `self` as the first parameter and including them in the body of a class.

Comment: Many thanks for this explanation. My conclusion is that a method is defined within a class like
```
class Testme:

    def __init__(self, starting):
        self.starting = starting
        print(f"""\n{starting}\n""")

    def callme(self):
        print("Hello")
```
here callme() is a method of class Testme?
on the other hand a function is just any function like abs(-3) etc that can be called anywhere

Comment: You're correct - and the reason to collect functions as methods in a class is usually because they share some data in the object, which helps avoid defining globals (which have their own problems). You can define and reference variables on the object with `self.var_name` and they will be available in the methods under that name (because `self` is passed as the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a method as argument to another method, but in your example you are creating an argument named `with_price`, which is unrelated to your function. You probably want to use `with_price` as a default argument for `a_method`. In my example I'll call the new argument `func`.

```py
def with_price(price: float, factor: float = 2.0):
    return (price * factor)
    
def a_method(a: float, func=with_price):
    b = func(11)
    return a * b
print(a_method(1))
```

Comment: Hi Franz is there any difference between an argument and parameter or they are just synonyms in this case (can be used interchangeably) ? Thanks

Comment: Just synonyms in this case. Here's a thread regarding this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter