# Are there built-in parameters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, parameters

Where do arguments like `element`, `index` and `array` come from, for e.g. the `filter` method like below:

```js
const arr = [ "Laurence", "Mike", "Larry", "Kim", "Joanne", "Laurence", "Mike", "Laurence", "Mike", "Laurence", "Mike" ];
const arr2 = arr.filter((value, index, array) => {
    console.log(value, index, array.indexOf(value));
    return array.indexOf(value) === index;
});
console.log(arr2);
```

In some built-in methods we use them, I know what they do, but I don’t understand if they are like built-in parameters.

For example, when one defines a function one would add parameters like `value`, `index` and `array`.

But when one calls the function one doesn’t add any arguments.

Are these kind of parameters like built-in parameters or why we don’t have to specify what they are?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom filter function to show you that these parameters aren't built-in, they are just passed to your callback by the `Array.prototype.filter` function when the internal loop is executed.

```js
const result = filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], item => item % 2 === 0)

console.log(result)

function filter(array, callback) {
  const newArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    // pass value index and array
    if (callback(array[i], i, array)) {
      newArray.push(array[i])
    }
  }
  return newArray
}
```

`forEach` example:

```js
forEach([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], (value, index) => console.log(value, index))


function forEach(array, callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    callback(array[i], i, array)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, **No there aren't**

Comment: It's an answer. But it could really be improved by further explanation. This question just got closed as a duplicate though, which I think is the better outcome.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions are objects like any other -- you can pass functions to functions. This is how the [`Array.prototype.filter`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function (the `filter` method you'd call on an array like `arr.filter(...)`) works -- it takes a function as a parameter. It filters by calling the function you pass to `filter`, for every element, with the element [of the array] as `value`, the index of the element [in the array] as `index`, and the array itself as `array`. If your function returns `true`, the element is contained in the array returned by `filter`, otherwise the element isn't contained in the returned array.

So yes, the `filter` function is what calls the function you pass to `filter`, *binding* parameters to values -- something that makes parameters *arguments*.

In JavaScript, if you do not pass an argument to a function that expects an argument, the argument is `undefined` -- you can say that the parameter isn't bound:

```
function f(a) {
     return a;
}
console.assert(f() === undefined); /// Yields true
```

JavaScript will *not* warn you that an argument is missing.

That is all there is to it, really.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question largely involves the difference between the terms "parameter" and "argument", also known as "formal parameters" and "actual arguments".

This canonical question, [What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/156767/5217142) covers the subject with external links.

**Summary**

- A (formal) parameter is the name used when coding or documenting a function to identify an argument that will be passed to it.
- An (actual) argument is the value of a (formal) parameter passed to a function when called.

Code that calls a function can supply arguments using literal values, or values held in variables or object properties. Calling code may choose to name variables after documented parameter names of a called function - but is not required to do so.

**Posted code**

```
arr.filter((value, index, array) => {
   console.log(value, index, array.indexOf(value));
   return array.indexOf(value) === index;
});
```

Here the array method `Array.prototype.filter` is called with a callback function argument, being the in-lined anonymous function, `(value, index, array)=>{ /* code */}`.

- `value`, `index` and `array` are the call back function's parameter names, chosen by the person who wrote the code to be readable in English. If they wanted the code to be readable in French, say, they might have used [`elementCourant`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of `value`.
- "value", "index" and "array" are the terms used in [(MDN) English documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of arguments passed to the callback by the filter method.

**TL:DR**

In general look up the documentation for standard JavaScript methods  to find out what arguments are passed to callbacks they make. You can use callback argument names from the documentation as formal parameter names in callback functions you write - if you want to and it suits your purpose.