# How are arguments translated to parameters?

Tags: python, function

I was able to solve this lab after some trial and error but what confuses me is how do the parameters (base_length,base_width) get their information.

```
def calc_base_area(base_length, base_width):
    return base_length * base_width

def calc_pyramid_volume(base_length, base_width, pyramid_height):
    return calc_base_area(base_length, base_width)  * height * 1/3

length = float(input())
width = float(input())
height = float(input())
print(f'Volume for {length} {width} {height} is: {calc_pyramid_volume(length, width, height):.2f}')
```

This part below is the only part that I added, the rest was preset. I am just struggling to understand how the system takes the length, width, and height and turns it into base_length, base_width, and pyramid_height.

```
def calc_pyramid_volume(base_length, base_width, pyramid_height):
    return calc_base_area(base_length, base_width)  * height * 1/3
```

Comment: The variables length, width and height store floats entered by the user. On the last line, in the `print` call, you pass these variables to the function call of `calc_pyramid_volume`. At that point, the values in those variables are "transferred" into the variables named `base_length`, `base_width` and `pyramid_height`. Because those are the names of the input arguments to that function. See also https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

Comment: In particular this quote from the linked article is relevant: "A function receives a reference to (and will access) the same object in memory as used by the caller. However, it does not receive the box that the caller is storing this object in; as in pass-by-value, the function provides its own box and creates a new variable for itself."

Comment: because you provide them with values when you call the function as arguments in that last line: `calc_pyramid_volume(length, width, height)`, what is it you don't understand? Did you just not see that because it was in an f-string? Do you understand how paramters in functions and arguments in function calls work? So do you understand `def foo(x): return x * 2` then `y = 1; print(foo(y))`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable

```
length = 2
```

You create a space in your computer's memory for the `length` variable. You then put the value assigned to it, in this case, 2, on the location you just created

When you pass this variable as a parameter of a function

```
length = 2
def calc_pyramid_volume(base_length)
calc_pyramid_volume(length)
```

The function will simply create a reference to the same space in your computer's memory. It's as if it created a secondary name for that space in your memory.

The same space is called `length` outside of the scope of your function, and `base_length` inside of the scope. That means your computer doesn't need to "turn" something into "another something". It just has multiple names for the same thing.

Maybe think of it as two signs that point to the same place, one from the left, the other from the right.

Comment: "You create a space in your computer's memory for the length variable" this is not how Python works, really.  For starters, python *doesn't have variable declarations*. But a variable is not some space in memory. This is how languages like C work, but not Python. A variable is simply a name that refers to some object in some namespace

Comment: The answer was obviously a simplification. The person that asked the question is very clearly just beginning and can't even understand how function calls work yet. I understand the concern, but why would one bother to go into more detail of how assignment works and risk ending up confusing OP even more?

Comment: but you are going into detail that is *wrong*. I'm saying give a more abstract, and correct, description.